# Generate SQL Create Scripts for existing tables with Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the CREATE scripts for existing tables within SQL Server 2008. I assume I can do this by querying the sys.tables somehow, however this isn't returning me the CREATE script data.

Comment: Just `CREATE TABLE` or all of the other baggage, e.g indexes, relations, check constraints, triggers _(With the firing order preserved!)_, ...?  As soon as you start adding relations the order of creation becomes critical.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Possible this be helpful for you. This script generate indexes, FK's, PK and common structure for any table.

For example -

**DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut](
    [WorkOutID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeSheetDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [DateOut] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsMainWorkPlace] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [WorkPlaceUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [TeamUID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [WorkShiftCD] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [WorkHours] [real] NULL,
    [AbsenceCode] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [PaymentType] [char](2) NULL,
    [CategoryID] [int] NULL,
    [Year]  AS (datepart(year,[TimeSheetDate])),
 CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkOut] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [WorkOutID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut] ADD  
CONSTRAINT [DF__WorkOut__IsMainW__2C1E8537]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [IsMainWorkPlace]

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_WorkOut_Employee_EmployeeID] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeID])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WorkOut_Employee_EmployeeID]
```

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
SELECT @table_name = 'dbo.WorkOut'

DECLARE 
      @object_name SYSNAME
    , @object_id INT

SELECT 
      @object_name = '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
    , @object_id = o.[object_id]
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE s.name + '.' + o.name = @table_name
    AND o.[type] = 'U'
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
          ic.[object_id]
        , ic.index_id
        , ic.is_descending_key
        , ic.is_included_column
        , c.name
    FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
),
fk_columns AS 
(
     SELECT 
          k.constraint_object_id
        , cname = c.name
        , rcname = rc.name
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
)
SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
            THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
            ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    WHEN t.name IN ('decimal', 'numeric')
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END 
        END + CHAR(13)
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
    ORDER BY c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
    + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                    (SELECT STUFF((
                         SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                         FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                         JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                         WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                             AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                             AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
            + ')' + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)
    + ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE ' CHECK' 
              END + 
              ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')' +
              ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE '' 
              END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE '' 
              END 
            + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
        WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
    + ISNULL(((SELECT
         CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END 
                + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON ' + @object_name + ' (' +
                STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                FROM index_column c
                WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                    AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
                    FROM index_column c
                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
        WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
            AND i.is_primary_key = 0
            AND i.[type] = 2
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ), '')

PRINT @SQL
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

**Output:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut]
(
      [WorkOutID] BIGINT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [TimeSheetDate] DATETIME NOT NULL
    , [DateOut] DATETIME NOT NULL
    , [EmployeeID] INT NOT NULL
    , [IsMainWorkPlace] BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT((1))
    , [DepartmentUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
    , [WorkPlaceUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
    , [TeamUID] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL
    , [WorkShiftCD] NVARCHAR(10) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
    , [WorkHours] REAL NULL
    , [AbsenceCode] VARCHAR(25) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
    , [PaymentType] CHAR(2) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
    , [CategoryID] INT NULL
    , [Year] AS (datepart(year,[TimeSheetDate]))
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_WorkOut] PRIMARY KEY ([WorkOutID] ASC)
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_WorkOut_Employee_EmployeeID] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmployeeID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_WorkOut_Employee_EmployeeID]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_WorkOut_WorkShiftCD_AbsenceCode] ON [dbo].[WorkOut] ([WorkShiftCD] ASC, [AbsenceCode] ASC)
INCLUDE ([WorkOutID], [WorkHours])
```

**Also check this article -**

[How to Generate a CREATE TABLE Script For an Existing Table: Part 1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/67b45a/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table/)

Comment: @Devart I have used this script..it working fine. But with SQL server 11.0.6523 (2012) version, missing some column from table. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Service Pack 2

Comment: @Neelam Sharma  please provide `DDL` of your table

Comment: @Devart I have updated my query, please see updated question for ddl : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998330/ms-sql-script-generating-different-ddl-on-different-machine

Comment: Make sure you use the updated SQL linked above, or you will drop the decimal places on numeric columns.

Comment: This does not work for my products table, it breaks with 82 fields, but it has more fields.

Comment: You should use `quotename()` instead of `'[' + thing + ']'`

Comment: @jacouh There's a bug in the script of devart. It doesn't take in consideration the 4000 char limits when concatenating strings

Comment: @Devart Your script working fine but I am getting Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 21
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type varchar for table :  ddl for table : dbo.bizparsing
Columns:
          ruleID(PK,bigint, not null)
          bizName(varchar(100),not null)
          bizID (FK,bigint, not null)

Comment: Thanks @Devart!  For others, to handle an index with a filter I had to add `+ CASE WHEN ISNULL(i.filter_definition,'') = '' THEN '' ELSE ' WHERE ' + i.filter_definition END` to line 136 before the `+ CHAR(13)`

Comment: How easy would it be to put this on a loop to return the result for each INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.TABLE_NAME ? Thanks

Comment: Very nice script; however, to get it to work properly with sqlcmd.exe (command-line) in interactive mode, I had to change all of the `CHAR(13)` to `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`

Comment: Some column data types are not working (anymore?): `char`, `binary` and `nchar` have no `MAX` option and `time2` should probably be `time`.

Comment: This is very helpful!  I can't use the built-in SSMS generation tools due to server URN conflicts, so this was a big time-saver.  If anyone gets an "Invalid Urn filter on server level" error while trying to run the "Script Table as" -> "CREATE To" context, try this query out.

Comment: However, I am not able to use NTEXT(8), as the above script generates for my NTEXT columns (I run SQL Server 2019). If 'ntext' is removed from the row with  WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar'_, 'ntext'_) then it works for me...

Comment: @NeelamSharma: There is a bug with the script when dealing with identity columns if the seed value or increment value exceeds char(1) as would be case if you are seeding / incrementing in negative or in greater than single digits. 

What worked for me was to replace the CHAR(1) with varchar in the final CASE statement in the SELECT

Comment: When your Identity's seed_value is greater than 9 you would need to replace `CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1))` with `CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS NVARCHAR(50))` (Edit queue is full)

Comment: I think there's a typo. When I run I get an error that `t` can't be found. I believe it's supposed to be `tp`.

Answer (score 22):

do you mean you wish to create a TSQL script which generates a CREATE script, or use the Management tools in SQL SERVER Management Studio to generate a Create script?

If it's the latter, it's a simply matter of right-clicking a table, and selecting Script Table As -> Create To -> New Query Window.

If you want the whole database scripted, then right click the database and select Tasks--> Generate Scripts... and then follow the wizard

otherwise it's a matter of selecting all sorts of fun things out of the various system tables.

Comment: I was actually looking for a way to pro grammatically get these, as this will be ran from a .NET app to generate a master script file.

Answer (score 8):

I realize this question is old, but it recently popped up in a search I just ran, so I thought I'd post an alternative to the above answer.

If you are looking to generate `create` scripts programmatically in .Net, I would highly recommend looking into [Server Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) (SMO) or [Distributed Management Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258911.aspx) (DMO) -- depending on which version of SQL Server you are using (the former is 2005+, the latter 2000).  Using these libraries, scripting a table is as easy as:

```
Server server      = new Server(".");
Database northwind = server.Databases["Northwind"];
Table categories   = northwind.Tables["Categories"];

StringCollection script = categories.Script();
string[] scriptArray    = new string[script.Count];

script.CopyTo(scriptArray, 0);
```

[Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1833/generate-scripts-for-database-objects-with-smo-for-sql-server/) is a blog post with more information.

Answer (score 7):

First of all I love the script written by devart and I wanted to use it, but I found some limitation, so I decided to improve it:

- I fixed the bug that limits the script at 4000 chars (it's still possible that some crazy table still exceeds the limits)
- I fixed the bug/limitation in case the table uses a nonclustered primary key
- I replaced '[' with quotename
- I added the name of the default constraints
- I changed the logic to identify the source table
- I added the possibility to drop and recreate the table and its FKs
- I added the possibility to generate specific attributes
- I added the support for table compression
- I added the possibility the generate the scripts for any number of tables
- I fixed the limitation of 4000 varchar() when printing the result
- I replaced '' with N''
- I added the option to generate messages during the execution, because my final script (with the insert into) can take so long that I want to know what it's doing
- I added the generation of an "Insert into"

I didn't have time to test it properly and I tested it only on SQL Server 2012/4

The next version will change the generation of FKs because they need to be added at the end. Otherwise they may fail.

Any comment will be appreciated.

```
set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
SET STATISTICS IO OFF;

-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639948/sql-nvarchar-and-varchar-limits
--NB: Crazy table can still have truncation at 4000 because of unexpected number of indexes or other very long list of columns/defaults etc
-- triggers are not supported
-- xml indexes are not supported

DECLARE @Tables table(id int identity(1,1), [name] sysname);
insert into @Tables([name])
values
   ('<yourSchema>.<youTableName>')
  ,('<yourSchema2>.<youTableName2>')
;
DECLARE @object_id                          int;
DECLARE @SourceDatabase nvarchar(max) = N'SourceTest'; --this is used only by the insert 
DECLARE @TargetDatabase nvarchar(max) = N'DescTest';   --this is used only by the insert and USE <DBName>

--- options ---
DECLARE @UseTransaction                     bit = 0; 
DECLARE @GenerateUseDatabase                bit = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateFKs                        bit = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateIdentity                   bit = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateCollation                  bit = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateCreateTable                bit = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateIndexes                    bit = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateConstraints                bit = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateKeyConstraints             bit = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateConstraintNameOfDefaults   bit = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateDropIfItExists             bit = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateDropFKIfItExists           bit = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateDelete                     bit = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateInsertInto                 bit = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateIdentityInsert             int = 0; --0 ignore set,but add column; 1 generate; 2 ignore set and column
DECLARE @GenerateSetNoCount                 int = 2; --0 ignore set,1=set on, 2=set off 
DECLARE @GenerateMessages                   bit = 1; --print with no wait
DECLARE @GenerateDataCompressionOptions     bit = 1; --TODO: generates the compression option only of the table, not the indexes
                                                    --NB: the compression options reflects the design value.
                                                    --The actual compression of a the page is saved here
                                                    --SELECT * from sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations(DB_ID(), @object_ID, 0, 1, 'DETAILED')

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- Let's play
DECLARE @DataTypeSpacer                     int = 45; --this is just to improve the formatting of the script ...
DECLARE @name                               sysname;
DECLARE @SQL                                NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT [name] from @Tables
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    SET @object_id = object_ID(@name)
    goto CreateScript;
backFromCreateScript:
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name 
END 
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor 
return;

CreateScript:

DECLARE @CR NVARCHAR(max) = NCHAR(13);
DECLARE @TB NVARCHAR(max) = NCHAR(9);
DECLARE @CurrentIndent nvarchar(max) = ''

;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
        ic.[object_id]
        , ic.index_id
        , ic.is_descending_key
        , ic.is_included_column
        , c.name
    FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
),
fk_columns AS 
(
    SELECT 
        k.constraint_object_id
        , cname = c.name
        , rcname = rc.name
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id and @GenerateFKs = 1
)
SELECT @SQL = 

    --------------------  USE DATABASE   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CAST(
            CASE WHEN @GenerateUseDatabase = 1
            THEN N'USE ' + @TargetDatabase + N';' + @CR
            ELSE N'' END 
        as nvarchar(max))
        +
    --------------------  SET NOCOUNT   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CAST(
            CASE @GenerateSetNoCount 
            WHEN 1 THEN N'SET NOCOUNT ON;' + @CR
            WHEN 2 THEN N'SET NOCOUNT OFF;' + @CR
            ELSE N'' END 
        as nvarchar(max))
        +
    --------------------  USE TRANSACTION  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CAST(
            CASE WHEN @UseTransaction = 1
            THEN 
                N'SET XACT_ABORT ON' + @CR
                + N'BEGIN TRY' + @CR
                + N'BEGIN TRAN' + @CR
            ELSE N'' END 
        as nvarchar(max))
        +
    --------------------  DROP SYNONYM   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CASE WHEN @GenerateDropIfItExists = 1
        THEN 
            CAST(
                    N'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N''',''SN'') IS NOT NULL DROP SYNONYM ' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N';' + @CR 
            as nvarchar(max))
        ELSE 
            CAST(
                    N'' 
            as nvarchar(max))
        END 
        +
    --------------------  DROP IS Exists --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CASE WHEN @GenerateDropIfItExists = 1
        THEN 
            --Drop table if exists
            CAST(
                N'IF OBJECT_ID(''' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N''',''U'') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE ' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N';' + @CR 
            as nvarchar(max))
            + @CR
        ELSE N'' END 
        +
    --------------------  DROP IS Exists --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 and @GenerateDropFKIfItExists = 1 THEN 
            N'RAISERROR(''DROP CONSTRAINTS OF %s'',10,1, ''' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N''') WITH NOWAIT;' + @CR            
        ELSE N'' END) as nvarchar(max)) 
        +
        CASE WHEN @GenerateDropFKIfItExists = 1
        THEN 
            --Drop foreign keys
            ISNULL(((
                SELECT 
                    CAST(
                        N'ALTER TABLE ' + quotename(s.name) + N'.' + quotename(t.name) + N' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + RTRIM(f.name) + N';' + @CR
                    as nvarchar(max))
                FROM sys.tables t
                INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys f ON f.parent_object_id = t.object_id
                INNER JOIN sys.schemas      s ON s.schema_id = f.schema_id
                WHERE f.referenced_object_id = @object_id
                FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))
            ,N'') + @CR
        ELSE N'' END 
    +
    --------------------- CREATE TABLE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 THEN 
        N'RAISERROR(''CREATE TABLE %s'',10,1, ''' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N''') WITH NOWAIT;' + @CR           
    ELSE N'' END) as nvarchar(max)) 
    +
    CASE WHEN @GenerateCreateTable = 1 THEN 
        CAST(
            N'CREATE TABLE ' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + @CR + N'(' + @CR + STUFF((
            SELECT 
                CAST(
                    @TB + N',' + quotename(c.name) + N' ' + ISNULL(replicate(' ',@DataTypeSpacer - len(quotename(c.name))),'')  --isnull(replicate) then len(quotename(c.name)) > @DataTypeSpacer
                    +  
                    CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
                        THEN N' AS ' + cc.[definition] 
                        ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                            CASE WHEN tp.name IN (N'varchar', N'char', N'varbinary', N'binary', N'text')
                                    THEN N'(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN N'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS NVARCHAR(5)) END + N')'
                                    WHEN tp.name IN (N'nvarchar', N'nchar', N'ntext')
                                    THEN N'(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN N'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS NVARCHAR(5)) END + N')'
                                    WHEN tp.name IN (N'datetime2', N'time2', N'datetimeoffset') 
                                    THEN N'(' + CAST(c.scale AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N')'
                                    WHEN tp.name = N'decimal' 
                                    THEN N'(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N',' + CAST(c.scale AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N')'
                                ELSE N''
                            END +
                            CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL and @GenerateCollation = 1 THEN N' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE N'' END +
                            CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN N' NULL' ELSE N' NOT NULL' END +
                            CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN @GenerateConstraintNameOfDefaults = 1 THEN N' CONSTRAINT ' + quotename(dc.name) ELSE N'' END + N' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE N'' END + 
                            CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 and @GenerateIdentity = 1 THEN N' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, N'0') AS NCHAR(1)) + N',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, N'1') AS NCHAR(1)) + N')' ELSE N'' END 
                    END + @CR
                AS nvarchar(Max))
            FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
                INNER JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
                LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
                LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
                LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
            WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, @TB + N' ')
    as nvarchar(max))
    ELSE 
        CAST('' as nvarchar(max)) 
    end 
    + 
    ---------------------- Key Constraints ----------------------------------------------------------------
    CAST(
        case when @GenerateKeyConstraints <> 1 THEN N'' ELSE 
            ISNULL((SELECT @TB + N', CONSTRAINT ' + quotename(k.name) + N' PRIMARY KEY ' + ISNULL(kidx.type_desc, N'') + N'(' + 
                        (SELECT STUFF((
                            SELECT N', ' + quotename(c.name) + N' ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN N'DESC' ELSE N'ASC' END
                            FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                            JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                            WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                                AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                                AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, N''))
                + N')' + @CR
                FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT) LEFT JOIN sys.indexes kidx ON
                    k.parent_object_id = kidx.object_id and k.unique_index_id = kidx.index_id
                WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                    AND k.[type] = N'PK'), N'') + N')'  + @CR
        END 
    as nvarchar(max))
    +
    CAST(
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            @GenerateDataCompressionOptions = 1 
            AND 
            (SELECT top 1 data_compression_desc from sys.partitions where object_ID = @object_id and index_id = 1) <> N'NONE'
        THEN 
            N'WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION=' + (SELECT top 1 data_compression_desc from sys.partitions where object_ID = @object_id and index_id = 1) + N')' + @CR
        ELSE
            N'' + @CR
    END as nvarchar(max))
    + 
    --------------------- FOREIGN KEYS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 and @GenerateDropFKIfItExists = 1 THEN 
        N'RAISERROR(''CREATING FK OF  %s'',10,1, ''' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N''') WITH NOWAIT;' + @CR            
    ELSE N'' END) as nvarchar(max)) 
    +
    CAST(
        ISNULL((SELECT (
            SELECT @CR +
            N'ALTER TABLE ' + + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + + N' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN N' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE N' CHECK' 
            END + 
            N' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + quotename(fk.name)  + N' FOREIGN KEY(' 
            + STUFF((
                SELECT N', ' + quotename(k.cname) + N''
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, N'')
            + N')' +
            N' REFERENCES ' + quotename(SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id])) + N'.' + quotename(ro.name) + N' ('
            + STUFF((
                SELECT N', ' + quotename(k.rcname) + N''
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, N'')
            + N')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN N' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN N' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN N' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE N'' 
            END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN N' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN N' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN N' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE N'' 
            END 
            + @CR + N'ALTER TABLE ' + + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + + N' CHECK CONSTRAINT ' + quotename(fk.name)  + N'' + @CR
        FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
        WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), N'')
    as nvarchar(max))
    + 
    --------------------- INDEXES ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 and @GenerateIndexes = 1 THEN 
        N'RAISERROR(''CREATING INDEXES OF  %s'',10,1, ''' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N''') WITH NOWAIT;' + @CR           
    ELSE N'' END) as nvarchar(max)) 
    +
    case when @GenerateIndexes = 1 THEN 
        CAST(
            ISNULL(((SELECT
                @CR + N'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN N' UNIQUE ' ELSE N' ' END 
                        + i.type_desc + N' INDEX ' + quotename(i.name) + N' ON ' + + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + + N' (' +
                        STUFF((
                        SELECT N', ' + quotename(c.name) + N'' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN N' DESC' ELSE N' ASC' END
                        FROM index_column c
                        WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                            AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, N'') + N')'  
                        + ISNULL(@CR + N'INCLUDE (' + 
                            STUFF((
                            SELECT N', ' + quotename(c.name) + N''
                            FROM index_column c
                            WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                                AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, N'') + N')', N'')  + @CR
                FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
                WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
                    AND i.is_primary_key = 0
                    AND i.[type] in (1,2)
                    and @GenerateIndexes = 1
                FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ), N'')
        as nvarchar(max))
    ELSE 
        CAST(N'' as nvarchar(max))
    END 
    +
    ------------------------  @GenerateDelete     ----------------------------------------------------------
    CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 and @GenerateDelete = 1 THEN 
        N'RAISERROR(''TRUNCATING  %s'',10,1, ''' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N''') WITH NOWAIT;' + @CR            
    ELSE N'' END) as nvarchar(max)) 
    +
    CASE WHEN @GenerateDelete = 1 THEN
        CAST(
            (CASE WHEN exists (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE referenced_object_id = @object_id) THEN 
                N'DELETE FROM ' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N';' + @CR
            ELSE
                N'TRUNCATE TABLE ' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N';' + @CR
            END)
        AS NVARCHAR(max))
    ELSE 
        CAST(N'' as nvarchar(max))
    END 
    +
    ------------------------- @GenerateInsertInto ----------------------------------------------------------
    CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 and @GenerateDropFKIfItExists = 1 THEN 
        N'RAISERROR(''INSERTING INTO  %s'',10,1, ''' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N''') WITH NOWAIT;' + @CR            
    ELSE N'' END) as nvarchar(max)) 
    +
    CASE WHEN @GenerateInsertInto = 1
    THEN 
        CAST(
                CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.columns c where c.[object_id] = @object_id and is_identity = 1) AND @GenerateIdentityInsert = 1 THEN 
                    N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N' ON;' + @CR
                ELSE 
                    CAST('' AS nvarchar(max))
                END 
                +
                N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDatabase) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N'(' 
                + @CR
                +
                (
                    @TB + N' ' + SUBSTRING(
                        (
                        SELECT @TB + ','+ quotename(Name) + @CR 
                        from sys.columns c 
                        where 
                                c.[object_id] = @object_id 
                            AND system_type_ID <> 189 /*timestamp*/ 
                            AND is_computed = 0
                            and (is_identity = 0 or @GenerateIdentityInsert in (0,1))
                        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                    ,3,99999)

                )
                + N')' + @CR + N'SELECT ' 
                + @CR
                +
                (
                    @TB + N' ' + SUBSTRING(
                        (
                        SELECT @TB + ','+ quotename(Name) + @CR 
                        FROM sys.columns c 
                        WHERE   c.[object_id] = @object_id 
                            and system_type_ID <> 189 /*timestamp*/ 
                            and is_computed = 0                     
                            and (is_identity = 0 or @GenerateIdentityInsert  in (0,1))
                        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                    ,3,99999)
                )
                + N'FROM ' + @SourceDatabase +  N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id))            
                + N';' + @CR
                + CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT * from sys.columns c where c.[object_id] = @object_id and is_identity = 1)  AND @GenerateIdentityInsert = 1 THEN 
                    N'SET IDENTITY_INSERT ' + quotename(OBJECT_schema_name(@object_id)) + N'.' + quotename(OBJECT_NAME(@object_id)) + N' OFF;'+ @CR
                ELSE 
                    CAST('' AS nvarchar(max))
                END              
        as nvarchar(max))
    ELSE 
        CAST(
                N'' 
        as nvarchar(max))
    END 
    +
    --------------------  USE TRANSACTION  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CAST(
        CASE WHEN @UseTransaction = 1
        THEN 
            @CR + N'COMMIT TRAN; '
            + @CR + N'END TRY'
            + @CR + N'BEGIN CATCH'
            + @CR + N'  IF XACT_STATE() IN (-1,1)'
            + @CR + N'      ROLLBACK TRAN;'
            + @CR + N''
            + @CR + N'  SELECT   ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  '
            + @CR + N'          ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  '
            + @CR + N'          ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  '
            + @CR + N'          ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  '
            + @CR + N'          ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  '
            + @CR + N'          ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; '
            + @CR + N'END CATCH'
        ELSE N'' END 
    as nvarchar(max))

--print is limited to 4000 chars, if necessary, I use multiple print
--to maintain the consistency of the script, I split near the closest CrLF to the max chunk size
DECLARE @i  int = 1;
DECLARE @maxChunk integer = 3990;
DECLARE @len integer = @maxChunk;

WHILE @i < len(@SQL)
BEGIN 
    IF len(@SQL) > (@i + @len)
        set @len = len(substring(@SQL, @i, @maxChunk)) - CHARINDEX(@CR, reverse(substring(@SQL, @i, @len))) + 1
    PRINT substring(@SQL, @i, @len)
    set @i      =  @i + @len
    set @len    =  @maxChunk
END

--SELECT datalength(@SQL), @sql
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

goto backFromCreateScript;
```

Comment: I'm getting an Invalid object error when I try to run this - `Invalid object name 'sys.Tables'.` Any ideas?

Comment: @Nick: sys.tables exists was introduces in SQL Server 2008. What version of SQL Server are you using? Can you execute "SELECT * from sys.tables" ? Have you tried to execute the version of the script written by DevArt? Do you have the same error?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2014, and no I can not execute `SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES` I receive the same Invalid object name error as above.

Comment: "SELECT * from sys.tables" is different from "SELECT * FROM SYS.TABLES". It was meant to check the database collation. Are you using a CS (case sensitive) database collation? Are you logged in as dbo? Is it possible that the compatibility level of your database is SQL Server 2005 (sys.tables exists starting from 2008)?

Comment: @Nick: I updated my script and changed sys.Tables to sys.table, let me know if you still have the problem. Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: Great script! I ran into a small issue because LEN doesn't count trailing spaces. Using len(mystring + 'X') - 1 fixes that. Also, in the print statement I found I needed to take @len - 1 as the length of the substring in order to NOT take the CR character, since Print inserts its own CR.

Comment: I also had to change the following line to change CAST to TRY_CAST and wrap in ISNULL to avoid occasional "Arithmetic overflow converting expression to datatype nvarchar" errors: CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 and @GenerateIdentity = 1 THEN N' IDENTITY(' + ISNULL(TRY_CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, N'0') AS NCHAR(1)),0) + N',' + ISNULL(TRY_CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, N'1') AS NCHAR(1)), 0) + N')' ELSE N'' END

Comment: I also changed the computed column definition to include the PERSISTED property: THEN N' AS ' + cc.[definition] + CASE WHEN cc.is_persisted = 1 THEN 'PERSISTED' ELSE '' END

Answer (score 5):

"Easiest way is to use the built-in feature of SQL Management Studio"
but...
I have resolved it with a function and a couple of procedures.
For example, to obtain the create table for a table named 'table_name', you have to execute just the procedure called sp_ppinScriptTabla:

```
Exec sp_ppinScriptTabla 'table_name'
```

Here is the tsql script code:

```
Use Master
GO

Create Function sp_ppinTipoLongitud
(
    @xtype int,
    @length int,
    @isnullable int
)
Returns Varchar(512)
As 
Begin
    -- Función que a partir de un tipo de datos y una logitud, devuelve el texto del tipo.
    -- Por ejemplo: para xtype=varchar y length=10 devolverá "varchar(10)"
    Declare @ret varchar(512)
    Set @ret = ''

    Select @ret = t.name +
    Case When name in ('varchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'nchar') Then '(' + Convert(varchar, @length) + ')' Else '' End + ' ' +
    Case @isnullable When 1 Then 'NULL' Else 'NOT NULL' End
    From systypes t 
    Where t.xtype = @xtype

    Return @ret
End
GO

Create Procedure sp_ppinScriptLlavesForaneas
(
    @vchTabla sysname,
    @vchResultado varchar(8000) output
)
AS 
Begin

    DECLARE @tmpFK table(
        TablaF sysname,
        TablaR sysname,
        ColF sysname,
        ColR sysname,
        FKName sysname)

    -- obtengo las llaves foraneas en @vchForeign
    Declare @vchForeign varchar(8000), @FKName sysname, @vchColumnasF varchar(4000), @vchColumnasR varchar(4000), @ColF sysname, @ColR sysname
    Declare @vchTemp varchar(1000), @TablaR sysname

    Insert into @tmpFK
    Select TablaF.name AS TablaF, TablaR.name AS TablaR, ColF.name AS ColF, ColR.name AS ColR, ofk.name AS FKName
    From sysforeignkeys fk, sysobjects ofk, sysobjects TablaF, sysobjects TablaR, 
    syscolumns ColF, syscolumns ColR
    Where TablaF.name = @vchTabla
    And ofk.id = fk.constid
    And TablaF.id = fk.fkeyid
    And TablaR.id = fk.rkeyid
    And ColF.id = TablaF.id And ColF.colid = fk.fkey
    And ColR.id = TablaR.id And ColR.colid = fk.rkey
    order by FKName

    Set @vchForeign = ''
    While Exists ( Select * From @tmpFK )
    Begin
        Select Top 1 @FKName = FKName From @tmpFK
        Set @vchColumnasF = ''
        Set @vchColumnasR = ''
        While Exists ( Select * From @tmpFK Where FKName = @FKName )
        Begin
            Select Top 1 @ColF = ColF, @ColR = ColR, @TablaR = TablaR From @tmpFK Where FKName = @FKName
            Delete From @tmpFK Where ColF = @ColF And ColR = @ColR And TablaR = @TablaR And FKName = @FKName
            Set @vchColumnasF = @vchColumnasF + @ColF + ', '
            Set @vchColumnasR = @vchColumnasR + @ColR + ', '
        End

        Set @vchColumnasF = LEFT(@vchColumnasF, LEN(@vchColumnasF) - 1)
        Set @vchColumnasR = LEFT(@vchColumnasR, LEN(@vchColumnasR) - 1)
        Set @vchTemp = 'Constraint ' + @FKName + ' Foreign Key (' + @vchColumnasF + ') '
        Set @vchTemp = @vchTemp + 'References ' + @TablaR + ' (' + @vchColumnasR + ')'
        Set @vchForeign = @vchForeign + char(9) + @vchTemp + ',' + char(13) 
    End

    Select @vchResultado = Case When Len(@vchForeign) >=2 Then Left(@vchForeign, Len(@vchForeign) - 2) Else @vchForeign End
End
GO

Create Procedure sp_ppinScriptTabla
(
    @vchTabla sysname
)
AS

Set nocount on

-- Obtengo las foreign keys
Declare @foreign varchar(8000)
Exec sp_ppinScriptLlavesForaneas @vchTabla, @foreign output

-- SELECT que devuelve el script de Create Table de la tabla
Select 'Create ' + 
Case o.xtype When 'U' Then 'Table' When 'P' Then 'Procedure' Else '??' End + ' ' +
@vchTabla + char(13) + '('
From sysobjects o
Where o.name = @vchTabla
Union all
-- Campos + identitys + DEFAULTS
select char(9) + c.name + ' ' +                                 -- Nombre
dbo.sp_ppinTipoLongitud(t.xtype, c.length, c.isnullable) +          -- Tipo(longitud)
Case When c.colstat & 1 = 1                                     -- Identity (si aplica)
    Then ' Identity(' + convert(varchar, ident_seed(@vchTabla)) + ',' + Convert(varchar, ident_incr(@vchTabla)) + ')' 
    Else '' 
End + 
Case When not od.name is null                                   -- Defaults (si aplica)
    Then ' Constraint ' + od.name + ' Default ' + replace(replace(cd.text, '((', '('), '))', ')')
    Else ''
End + ', '
from sysobjects o, syscolumns c
LEFT OUTER JOIN sysobjects od On od.id = c.cdefault LEFT OUTER join syscomments cd On cd.id = od.id, 
systypes t
where o.id = object_id(@vchTabla)
and o.id = c.id
and c.xtype = t.xtype
Union all
-- Primary Keys y Unique keys
select char(9) + 'Constraint ' + o.name + ' ' +
Case o.xtype When 'PK' Then 'Primary Key' Else 'Unique' End + ' ' +
dbo.sp_ppinCamposIndice (db_name(), @vchTabla, i.indid) + ', '
from sysobjects o, sysindexes i
where o.parent_obj = object_id(@vchTabla)
and o.xtype in ('PK','UQ')
and i.id = o.parent_obj
and o.name = i.name
Union all
-- Check constraints
select char(9) + 'Constraint ' + o.name + ' Check ' + c.text + ', '
from sysobjects o, syscomments c
where o.parent_obj = object_id(@vchTabla)
and o.xtype in ('C')
and o.id = c.id
Union all
-- Foreign keys
Select @foreign
Union all
Select ')'

Set nocount off
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/script-create-table-script-from-linked-server

For Linked Servers - on SQL Server - following works great -

```
SELECT *
INTO MyNewTable
FROM MyLinkedServer.DatabaseName.dbo.TargetTable
WHERE 1 = 0

--no data transferred, but the table gets built.
```

Comment: Great solution! However you have to take care of PK (and other constraints) manually.

Comment: Yes. Had to search and use this way because otherwise there was no way that I was going to manually create the table. I think it had more than 50 columns :).

Comment: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/script-create-table-script-from-linked-server did an excellent job by posting the solution online.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slight variation on @Devart 's answer so you can get the CREATE script for a temp table.

Please note that since the @SQL variable is an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` data type you might not be able to copy it from the result using just only SSMS. Please see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897950/how-do-you-view-all-text-from-an-ntext-or-nvarcharmax-in-ssms) to see how to get the full value of a **MAX** field.

```
DECLARE @temptable_objectid INT = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp');

DECLARE 
      @object_name SYSNAME
    , @object_id INT

SELECT  
      @object_name = '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
    , @object_id = o.[object_id]
FROM tempdb.sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN tempdb.sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE object_id = @temptable_objectid

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
          ic.[object_id]
        , ic.index_id
        , ic.is_descending_key
        , ic.is_included_column
        , c.name
    FROM tempdb.sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
),
fk_columns AS 
(
     SELECT 
          k.constraint_object_id
        , cname = c.name
        , rcname = rc.name
    FROM tempdb.sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN tempdb.sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
    JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
)
SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
            THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
            ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name = 'decimal' 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END 
        END + CHAR(13)
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN tempdb.sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    LEFT JOIN tempdb.sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
    LEFT JOIN tempdb.sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN tempdb.sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
    ORDER BY c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
    + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                    (SELECT STUFF((
                         SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                         FROM tempdb.sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                         JOIN tempdb.sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                         WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                             AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                             AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
            + ')' + CHAR(13)
            FROM tempdb.sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)
    + ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE ' CHECK' 
              END + 
              ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')' +
              ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE '' 
              END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE '' 
              END 
            + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM tempdb.sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN tempdb.sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
        WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
    + ISNULL(((SELECT
         CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END 
                + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON ' + @object_name + ' (' +
                STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                FROM index_column c
                WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                    AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
                    FROM index_column c
                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
        FROM tempdb.sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
        WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
            AND i.is_primary_key = 0
            AND i.[type] = 2
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ), '')

SELECT @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the built-in feature of SQL Management Studio.

Right-click the database, go to tasks, Generate Scripts, and walk through the wizard. You can choose what objects to script, and it'll make it all for you.

Now if you are trying to make your OWN script to do the same thing, you're probably up for a lot of work...

Comment: This worked for me and saved me a TON of time and potential errors.  It was unclear on what type of script the wizard would generate.  It does indeed generate a CREATE TABLE script if you select the table.  This answer was downvoted earlier.  Any particular reason why?

Comment: @jward01 *Shrug*. No idea, perhaps it would have received more votes with a detailed walk-through of the SSMS wizard, showing where you can choose to include options like indexes and foreign keys.

Comment: I can confirm in SSMS v18.0 preview (possibly earlier versions), you can open Object Explorer, expand your database, expand Programmability, expand Types, expand User-Defined Table Types, right-click your type and the "Script User-Defined Table Type as " option is there to choose the "CREATE To" script.

Comment: This is *not* the easiest way if you're trying to automate the process you're designing.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're offering alternatives to what you asked..

If you're in .Net, you should look at the Database Publishing Wizard in Visual Studio.  Easy way to script your tables/data to a text file.

http://www.codeplex.com/sqlhost/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Database%20Publishing%20Wizard

Answer (score 0):

Use the SSMS, easiest way
You can configure options for it as well (eg collation, syntax, drop...create)

Otherwise, SSMS Tools Pack, or DbFriend on CodePlex can help you generate scripts

Answer (score 0):

See my answer in this Question : [How to generate create script of table using SQL query in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213687/how-to-generate-create-script-of-table-using-sql-query-in-sql-server/19006647#19006647)

Use this query :

```
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_Table_Script]
Go

Create Function Get_Table_Script
(
    @vsTableName varchar(50)
)

Returns
    VarChar(Max)
With ENCRYPTION

Begin

Declare @ScriptCommand varchar(Max)

Select @ScriptCommand =
    ' Create Table [' + SO.name + '] (' + o.list + ')' 
    +
    (
        Case
        When TC.Constraint_Name IS NULL 
            Then ''
        Else 'ALTER TABLE ' + SO.Name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' +
            TC.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY ' + ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + ')'
        End
    )
From sysobjects As SO
    Cross Apply

    (
        Select 
            '  [' + column_name + '] ' + 
             data_type + 
             (
                Case data_type
                    When 'sql_variant' 
                        Then ''
                    When 'text' 
                        Then ''
                    When 'decimal' 
                        Then '(' + Cast( numeric_precision_radix As varchar ) + ', ' + Cast( numeric_scale As varchar ) + ') '
                    Else Coalesce( '(' + 
                                        Case 
                                            When character_maximum_length = -1 
                                                Then 'MAX'
                                            Else Cast( character_maximum_length As VarChar ) 
                                        End + ')' , ''
                                 ) 
                End 
            ) 
            + ' ' +
            (
                Case 
                    When Exists ( 
                                    Select id 
                                    From syscolumns
                                    Where 
                                        ( object_name(id) = SO.name )
                                        And 
                                        ( name = column_name )
                                        And 
                                        ( columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 )
                                ) 
                        Then 'IDENTITY(' + 
                                Cast( ident_seed(SO.name) As varchar ) + ',' + 
                                Cast( ident_incr(SO.name) As varchar ) + ')'

                    Else ''

                End
            ) + ' ' +

            (
                Case 
                    When IS_NULLABLE = 'No' 
                        Then 'NOT ' 
                    Else '' 
                End 
            ) + 'NULL ' + 
            (
                Case 
                    When information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL 
                        Then 'DEFAULT ' + information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT 
                    ELse '' 
                End 
            ) + ', ' 
        From information_schema.columns 
        Where 
            ( table_name = SO.name )
        Order by ordinal_position
        FOR XML PATH('')) o (list)

        Inner Join information_schema.table_constraints As TC On (
                                                                    ( TC.Table_name = SO.Name )
                                                                    AND 
                                                                    ( TC.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY' )
                                                                    And 
                                                                    ( TC.TABLE_NAME = @vsTableName )
                                                                 )
        Cross Apply
            (
                Select '[' + Column_Name + '], '
                From  information_schema.key_column_usage As kcu
                Where 
                    ( kcu.Constraint_Name = TC.Constraint_Name )
                Order By ORDINAL_POSITION
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) As j (list)
Where
    ( xtype = 'U' )
    AND 
    ( Name NOT IN ('dtproperties') )

Return @ScriptCommand

End
```

And you can fire this `Function` like this :

```
Select [dbo].Get_Table_Script '<Your_Table_Name>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Devart and @ildanny solutions...

I had the need to run this for ALL tables in a db and also to execute the code against Linked Servers.

All tables...

```
/*
Ex. 
EXEC etl.GetTableDefinitions '{friendlyname}', '{DatabaseName}', 'All', 0, NULL;
EXEC etl.GetTableDefinitions '{friendlyname}', '{DatabaseName}', 'dbo', 0, NULL;
EXEC etl.GetTableDefinitions '{friendlyname}', '{DatabaseName}', 'All', 1, '{linkedservername}';
*/
CREATE PROCEDURE etl.GetTableDefinitions
(
  @SystemName NVARCHAR(128)
, @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(128)
, @SchemaName NVARCHAR(128)
, @linkedserver BIT
, @linkedservername NVARCHAR(128)
)

AS

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @inSchemaName NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @inSchemaName = CASE WHEN @SchemaName = N'All' THEN N's.[name]' ELSE '''' + @SchemaName + '''' END;

IF @linkedserver = 0
BEGIN

SELECT @sql = N'
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--- options ---
DECLARE @UseTransaction BIT = 0; 
DECLARE @GenerateUseDatabase BIT = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateFKs BIT = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateIdentity BIT = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateCollation BIT = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateCreateTable BIT = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateIndexes BIT = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateConstraints BIT = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateKeyConstraints BIT = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateConstraintNameOfDefaults BIT = 1;
DECLARE @GenerateDropIfItExists BIT = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateDropFKIfItExists BIT = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateDelete BIT = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateInsertInto BIT = 0;
DECLARE @GenerateIdentityInsert INT = 0; --0 ignore set,but add column; 1 generate; 2 ignore set AND column
DECLARE @GenerateSetNoCount INT = 0; --0 ignore set,1=set on, 2=set off 
DECLARE @GenerateMessages BIT = 0; --print with no wait
DECLARE @GenerateDataCompressionOptions BIT = 0; --TODO: generates the compression option only of the TABLE, not the indexes
                                                    --NB: the compression options reflects the design VALUE.
                                                    --The actual compression of a the page is saved here
--- variables ---
DECLARE @DataTypeSpacer INT = 1; --this is just to improve the formatting of the script ...
DECLARE @name SYSNAME;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'''';
DECLARE @int INT = 1;
DECLARE @maxint INT;
DECLARE @SourceDatabase NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''' + @DatabaseName + '''; --this is used by the INSERT 
DECLARE @TargetDatabase NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''' + @DatabaseName + '''; --this is used by the INSERT AND USE <DBName>
DECLARE @cr NVARCHAR(20) = NCHAR(13);
DECLARE @tab NVARCHAR(20) = NCHAR(9);

DECLARE @Tables TABLE
(
      id INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [name] SYSNAME
    , [object_id] INT 
    , [database_id] SMALLINT
);

BEGIN 

    INSERT INTO @Tables([name], [object_id], [database_id])
    SELECT s.[name] + N''.'' + t.[name] AS [name]
        , t.[object_id]
        , DB_ID(''' + @DatabaseName + ''') AS [database_id]
    FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.tables t
        JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.schemas s ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE t.[name] NOT IN (''Tally'',''LOC_AND_SEG_CAP1'',''LOC_AND_SEG_CAP2'',''LOC_AND_SEG_CAP3'',''LOC_AND_SEG_CAP4'',''TableNames'')
        AND s.[name] = ' + @inSchemaName + '
    ORDER BY s.[name], t.[name];

    SELECT @maxint = COUNT(0) 
    FROM @Tables;

    WHILE @int <= @maxint
    BEGIN

        ;WITH 
        index_column AS 
        (
            SELECT ic.[object_id]
                , OBJECT_NAME(ic.[object_id], DB_ID(N''' + @DatabaseName + ''')) AS ObjectName
                , ic.index_id
                , ic.is_descending_key
                , ic.is_included_column
                , c.[name] 
            FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOLOCK)
                JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c WITH (NOLOCK) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] 
                    AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
                JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.tables t ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
        ) 
        , fk_columns AS 
        (
            SELECT k.constraint_object_id
                , cname = c.[name]
                , rcname = rc.[name]
            FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
                JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id 
                    AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
                JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                    AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
                JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.tables t ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
            WHERE @GenerateFKs = 1
        )
        SELECT @sql = @sql +

            --------------------  USE DATABASE   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CAST(
                    CASE WHEN @GenerateUseDatabase = 1
                    THEN N''USE '' + @TargetDatabase + N'';'' + @cr
                    ELSE N'''' END 
                AS NVARCHAR(200))
                +
            --------------------  SET NOCOUNT   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CAST(
                    CASE @GenerateSetNoCount 
                    WHEN 1 THEN N''SET NOCOUNT ON;'' + @cr
                    WHEN 2 THEN N''SET NOCOUNT OFF;'' + @cr
                    ELSE N'''' END 
                AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                +
            --------------------  USE TRANSACTION  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CAST(
                    CASE WHEN @UseTransaction = 1
                    THEN 
                        N''SET XACT_ABORT ON'' + @cr
                        + N''BEGIN TRY'' + @cr
                        + N''BEGIN TRAN'' + @cr
                    ELSE N'''' END 
                AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                +
            --------------------  DROP SYNONYM   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CASE WHEN @GenerateDropIfItExists = 1
                THEN CAST(N''IF OBJECT_ID('''''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'''''',''''SN'''') IS NOT NULL DROP SYNONYM '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'';'' + @cr AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                ELSE CAST(N'''' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))   END 
                +
            --------------------  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CASE WHEN @GenerateDropIfItExists = 1
                THEN 
                    --Drop TABLE if EXISTS
                    CAST(N''IF OBJECT_ID('''''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'''''',''''U'''') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'';'' + @cr AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                    + @cr
                ELSE N'''' END 
                +
            --------------------  DROP CONSTRAINT IF EXISTS --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 AND @GenerateDropFKIfItExists = 1 THEN 
                    N''RAISERROR(''''DROP CONSTRAINTS OF %s'''',10,1, '''''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'''''') WITH NOWAIT;'' + @cr            
                ELSE N'''' END) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                +
                CASE WHEN @GenerateDropFKIfItExists = 1
                THEN 
                    --Drop foreign keys
                    ISNULL(((
                        SELECT 
                            CAST(
                                N''ALTER TABLE '' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + N'' DROP CONSTRAINT '' + RTRIM(f.[name]) + N'';'' + @cr
                            AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                        FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.tables t
                            INNER JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.foreign_keys f ON f.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
                            INNER JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.schemas s ON s.[schema_id] = f.[schema_id]
                        WHERE f.referenced_object_id = t.[object_id]
                        FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)''))
                    , N'''') + @cr
                ELSE N'''' END 
            +
            --------------------- CREATE TABLE -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 THEN 
                N''RAISERROR(''''CREATE TABLE %s'''',10,1, '''''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'''''') WITH NOWAIT;'' + @cr           
            ELSE CAST(N'''' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) END) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
            +
            CASE WHEN @GenerateCreateTable = 1 THEN 
                CAST(
                    N''CREATE TABLE '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + @cr + N''('' + @cr + STUFF((
                    SELECT 
                        CAST(
                            @tab + N'','' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N'' '' + ISNULL(REPLICATE('' '',@DataTypeSpacer - LEN(QUOTENAME(c.[name]))),'''') 
                            +  
                            CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
                                THEN N'' AS '' + cc.[definition] 
                                ELSE UPPER(tp.[name]) + 
                                    CASE WHEN tp.[name] IN (N''varchar'', N''char'', N''varbinary'', N''binary'', N''text'')
                                            THEN N''('' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN N''MAX'' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS NVARCHAR(5)) END + N'')''
                                            WHEN tp.[name] IN (N''NVARCHAR'', N''nchar'', N''ntext'')
                                            THEN N''('' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN N''MAX'' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS NVARCHAR(5)) END + N'')''
                                            WHEN tp.[name] IN (N''datetime2'', N''time2'', N''datetimeoffset'') 
                                            THEN N''('' + CAST(c.scale AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N'')''
                                            WHEN tp.[name] = N''decimal'' 
                                            THEN N''('' + CAST(c.[precision] AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N'','' + CAST(c.scale AS NVARCHAR(5)) + N'')''
                                        ELSE N''''
                                    END +
                                    CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL AND @GenerateCollation = 1 THEN N'' COLLATE '' + c.collation_name ELSE N'''' END +
                                    CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN N'' NULL'' ELSE N'' NOT NULL'' END +
                                    CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN CASE WHEN @GenerateConstraintNameOfDefaults = 1 THEN N'' CONSTRAINT '' + QUOTENAME(dc.[name]) ELSE N'''' END + N'' DEFAULT'' + dc.[definition] ELSE N'''' END + 
                                    CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 AND @GenerateIdentity = 1 THEN N'' IDENTITY('' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, N''0'') AS NCHAR(1)) + N'','' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, N''1'') AS NCHAR(1)) + N'')'' ELSE N'''' END 
                            END + @cr
                        AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
                    FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
                        INNER JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
                        LEFT JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] 
                            AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
                        LEFT JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 
                            AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id 
                            AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
                        LEFT JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 
                            AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] 
                            AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                    WHERE c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
                    ORDER BY c.column_id
                    FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, @tab + N'' '') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            ELSE CAST(N'''' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) END 
            + 
            ---------------------- Key Constraints ----------------------------------------------------------------
            CAST(
                CASE WHEN @GenerateKeyConstraints <> 1 THEN N'''' 
                ELSE 
                    ISNULL((SELECT @tab + N'', CONSTRAINT '' + QUOTENAME(k.[name]) + N'' PRIMARY KEY '' + ISNULL(kidx.[type_desc], N'''') + N''('' + 
                                (SELECT STUFF((
                                    SELECT N'', '' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N'' '' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN N''DESC'' ELSE N''ASC'' END
                                    FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                                        JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] 
                                            AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                                    WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                                        AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                                        AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                                    FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, N''''))
                        + N'')'' + @cr
                        FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT) 
                            LEFT JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.indexes kidx ON k.parent_object_id = kidx.[object_id] 
                                AND k.unique_index_id = kidx.index_id
                        WHERE k.parent_object_id = t.[object_id] 
                            AND k.[type] = N''PK''), N'''') + N'')''  + @cr
                END 
            AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            +
            CAST(
            CASE 
                WHEN @GenerateDataCompressionOptions = 1 AND (SELECT TOP 1 data_compression_desc FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.partitions WHERE OBJECT_ID = t.[object_id] AND index_id = 1) <> N''NONE''
                THEN N''WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION='' + (SELECT TOP 1 data_compression_desc FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.partitions WHERE OBJECT_ID = t.[object_id] AND index_id = 1) + N'')'' + @cr
                ELSE N'''' + @cr
            END AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            + 
            --------------------- FOREIGN KEYS -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 AND @GenerateDropFKIfItExists = 1 THEN 
                N''RAISERROR(''''CREATING FK OF  %s'''',10,1, '''''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'''''') WITH NOWAIT;'' + @cr            
            ELSE N'''' END) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
            +
            CAST(
                ISNULL((SELECT (
                    SELECT @cr +
                    N''ALTER TABLE '' +  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) +  N'' WITH'' 
                    + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                        THEN N'' NOCHECK'' 
                        ELSE N'' CHECK'' 
                    END + 
                    N'' ADD CONSTRAINT '' + QUOTENAME(fk.[name])  + N'' FOREIGN KEY('' 
                    + STUFF((
                        SELECT N'', '' + QUOTENAME(k.cname) + N''''
                        FROM fk_columns k
                        WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                            AND fk.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
                        FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, N'''')
                    + N'')'' +
                    N'' REFERENCES '' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(ro.[name]) + N'' (''
                    + STUFF((
                        SELECT N'', '' + QUOTENAME(k.rcname) + N''''
                        FROM fk_columns k
                        WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                            AND fk.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
                        FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, N'''')
                    + N'')''
                    + CASE 
                        WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN N'' ON DELETE CASCADE'' 
                        WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN N'' ON DELETE SET NULL''
                        WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN N'' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT'' 
                        ELSE N'''' 
                    END
                    + CASE 
                        WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN N'' ON UPDATE CASCADE''
                        WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN N'' ON UPDATE SET NULL''
                        WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN N'' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT''  
                        ELSE N'''' 
                    END 
                    + @cr + N''ALTER TABLE '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'' CHECK CONSTRAINT '' + QUOTENAME(fk.[name])  + N'''' + @cr
                FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
                    JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
                WHERE fk.parent_object_id = t.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)'')), N'''')
            AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            + 
            --------------------- INDEXES ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 AND @GenerateIndexes = 1 THEN 
                N''RAISERROR(''''CREATING INDEXES OF  %s'''',10,1, '''''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'''''') WITH NOWAIT;'' + @cr           
            ELSE N'''' END) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
            +
            CASE WHEN @GenerateIndexes = 1 THEN 
                CAST(
                    ISNULL(((SELECT
                        @cr + N''CREATE'' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN N'' UNIQUE '' ELSE N'' '' END 
                                + i.[type_desc] + N'' INDEX '' + QUOTENAME(i.[name]) + N'' ON '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'' ('' +
                                STUFF((
                                SELECT N'', '' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N'''' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN N'' DESC'' ELSE N'' ASC'' END
                                FROM index_column c
                                WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                                    AND c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
                                    AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                                FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, N'''') + N'')''  
                                + ISNULL(@cr + N''INCLUDE ('' + 
                                    STUFF((
                                    SELECT N'', '' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N''''
                                    FROM index_column c
                                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                                        AND c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
                                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                                    FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)''), 1, 2, N'''') + N'')'', N'''')  + @cr
                        FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
                        WHERE i.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
                            AND i.is_primary_key = 0
                            AND i.[type] in (1,2)
                            AND @GenerateIndexes = 1
                        FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)'')
                    ), N'''')
                AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            ELSE N'''' END 
            +
            ------------------------  @GenerateDelete     ----------------------------------------------------------
            CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 AND @GenerateDelete = 1 THEN 
                N''RAISERROR(''''TRUNCATING  %s'''',10,1, '''''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'''''') WITH NOWAIT;'' + @cr            
            ELSE N'''' END) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
            +
            CASE WHEN @GenerateDelete = 1 THEN
                CAST(
                    (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 [name] FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.foreign_keys WHERE referenced_object_id = t.[object_id]) THEN 
                        N''DELETE FROM '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'';'' + @cr
                    ELSE
                        N''TRUNCATE TABLE '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'';'' + @cr
                    END)
                AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            ELSE N'''' END 
            +
            ------------------------- @GenerateInsertInto ----------------------------------------------------------
            CAST((CASE WHEN @GenerateMessages = 1 AND @GenerateDropFKIfItExists = 1 THEN 
                N''RAISERROR(''''INSERTING INTO  %s'''',10,1, '''''' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'''''') WITH NOWAIT;'' + @cr            
            ELSE N'''' END) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
            +
            CASE WHEN @GenerateInsertInto = 1
            THEN 
                CAST(
                        CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 c.[name] FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c WHERE c.[object_id] = t.[object_id] AND c.is_identity = 1) AND @GenerateIdentityInsert = 1 THEN 
                            N''SET IDENTITY_INSERT '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'' ON;'' + @cr
                        ELSE N'''' END 
                        +
                        N''INSERT INTO '' + QUOTENAME(@TargetDatabase) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''('' 
                        + @cr
                        +
                        (
                            @tab + N'' '' + SUBSTRING(
                                (
                                SELECT @tab + '',''+ QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + @cr 
                                FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c 
                                WHERE c.[object_id] = t.[object_id] 
                                    AND c.system_type_ID <> 189 /*timestamp*/ 
                                    AND c.is_computed = 0
                                    AND (c.is_identity = 0 or @GenerateIdentityInsert in (0,1))
                                FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)'')
                            ,3,99999)

                        )
                        + N'')'' + @cr + N''SELECT '' 
                        + @cr
                        +
                        (
                            @tab + N'' '' + SUBSTRING(
                                (
                                SELECT @tab + '',''+ QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + @cr 
                                FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c 
                                WHERE c.[object_id] = t.[object_id] 
                                    AND c.system_type_ID <> 189 /*timestamp*/ 
                                    AND c.is_computed = 0                     
                                    AND (c.is_identity = 0 or @GenerateIdentityInsert  in (0,1))
                                FOR XML PATH(N''''), TYPE).value(N''.'', N''NVARCHAR(MAX)'')
                            ,3,99999)
                        )
                        + N''FROM '' + @SourceDatabase +  N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id]))            
                        + N'';'' + @cr
                        + CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 c.[name] FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c WHERE c.[object_id] = t.[object_id] AND c.is_identity = 1) AND @GenerateIdentityInsert = 1 THEN 
                            N''SET IDENTITY_INSERT '' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N''.'' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(t.[object_id], t.[database_id])) + N'' OFF;''+ @cr
                        ELSE N'''' END              
                AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
            ELSE N'''' END 
            +
            --------------------  USE TRANSACTION  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CAST(
                CASE WHEN @UseTransaction = 1
                THEN 
                    @cr + N''COMMIT TRAN; ''
                    + @cr + N''END TRY''
                    + @cr + N''BEGIN CATCH''
                    + @cr + N''  IF XACT_STATE() IN (-1,1)''
                    + @cr + N''      ROLLBACK TRAN;''
                    + @cr + N''''
                    + @cr + N''  SELECT   ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  ''
                    + @cr + N''          ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  ''
                    + @cr + N''          ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  ''
                    + @cr + N''          ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  ''
                    + @cr + N''          ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  ''
                    + @cr + N''          ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage; ''
                    + @cr + N''END CATCH''
                ELSE N'''' END 
            AS NVARCHAR(700))
        FROM @Tables t
        WHERE ID = @int
        ORDER BY [name]; 
    
        SET @int = @int + 1;
    
    END

    EXEC [master].dbo.PrintMax @sql;
/* see below for PrintMax code*/

END'

EXEC (@sql);

END
ELSE
```

And the Linked Server bit...

```
BEGIN

SELECT @sql = N'EXECUTE (''
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN

... Same code but be sure to double up on your single quotes

END

... code for the printmax proc (not mine, @Ben B) because it may not exist at destination server

    DECLARE @CurrentEnd BIGINT; /* track the length of the next substring */
    DECLARE @offset TINYINT; /*tracks the amount of offset needed */
    DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @String = REPLACE(REPLACE(@sql, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), CHAR(10)), CHAR(13), CHAR(10))

    WHILE LEN(@String) > 1
    BEGIN
        IF CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @String) BETWEEN 1 AND 4000
        BEGIN
            SET @CurrentEnd = CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), @String) -1
            SET @offset = 2
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @CurrentEnd = 4000
            SET @offset = 1
        END   
        PRINT SUBSTRING(@String, 1, @CurrentEnd) 
        SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String, @CurrentEnd + @offset, LEN(@String))   
    END

END'') AT [' + @linkedservername + ']';

EXEC (@sql);

END
```

[Ben B solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850477/how-to-print-varcharmax-using-print-statement/10206672)

Answer (score 0):

@Devart : Thank you,The answer was perfect, I'm adding something which I found while coding.

@ildanny : Thank you for removing the word limitation

my inferences:

1. Added Default and Check constraints
2. Changed Identity :
   varchar(max) from char(1) : some tables may start from large numbers
3. Triggers can also be added as they are part of table, the definition
   is directly available from `select object_id from sys.triggers'`

```
.
.
.
CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' CONSTRAINT ' + quotename(dc.name) + ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
CASE WHEN ck.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' CONSTRAINT ' + quotename(ck.name) + ' CHECK' + ck.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS VARCHAR) + ')' ELSE '' END 
.
.
.
LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
LEFT JOIN sys.check_constraints ck WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ck.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = ck.parent_column_id 
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following of [Devart's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16797460/10027033),

If you want add extended property of a table, add this code to end of [Devart's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16797460/10027033):

```
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT CHAR(10)+Codes FROM (
        SELECT
            CONCAT(
            'EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N''MS_Description'', @value=N''', CAST(EP.value AS nvarchar),'''', --Value
            ', @level0type=N''SCHEMA'',@level0name=N''',S.name,'''', --Schema
            ', @level1type=N''TABLE'',@level1name=N''',O.name,'''', --Table
            ISNULL(', @level2type=N''COLUMN'',@level2name=N'''+C.name+'''', '') --Column
            , CHAR(10), 'GO') As Codes
        FROM
            sys.all_objects O WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN
            sys.schemas S WITH (NOWAIT) ON S.schema_id = O.schema_id
        LEFT JOIN
            sys.extended_properties EP WITH (NOWAIT) ON EP.major_id = O.object_id
        LEFT JOIN
            sys.columns AS C WITH (NOWAIT) ON EP.minor_id = C.column_id AND EP.major_id = C.object_id
        WHERE
            S.name+'.'+O.name = @table_name
    ) A
    FOR XML PATH('')
)

--replace XML escape characters
SET @SQL2=REPLACE(@SQL2, '&#x0D;', CHAR(13))
SET @SQL2=REPLACE(@SQL2, '&quot;', '"')
SET @SQL2=REPLACE(@SQL2, '&apos;', '''')
SET @SQL2=REPLACE(@SQL2, '&amp;', '&')
SET @SQL2=REPLACE(@SQL2, '&lt;', '<')
SET @SQL2=REPLACE(@SQL2, '&gt;', '>')   


PRINT @SQL2
```

and If you wants to add triggers of a table, add this code to end of [Devart's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16797460/10027033):

```
DECLARE @SQL3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT CHAR(10)+Codes FROM (
        SELECT OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) + CHAR(10) + 'GO' Codes
        FROM
            sys.objects O WITH (NOWAIT)
        WHERE type = 'TR' AND O.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table_name)
    ) A
    FOR XML PATH('')
);

--replace XML escape characters
SET @SQL3=REPLACE(@SQL3, '&#x0D;', CHAR(13))
SET @SQL3=REPLACE(@SQL3, '&quot;', '"')
SET @SQL3=REPLACE(@SQL3, '&apos;', '''')
SET @SQL3=REPLACE(@SQL3, '&amp;', '&')
SET @SQL3=REPLACE(@SQL3, '&lt;', '<')
SET @SQL3=REPLACE(@SQL3, '&gt;', '>')

DECLARE @i  int = 1;
DECLARE @maxChunk integer = 3990;
DECLARE @len integer = @maxChunk;

WHILE @i < len(@SQL3)
BEGIN 
    IF len(@SQL3) > (@i + @len)
        set @len = len(substring(@SQL3, @i, @maxChunk)) - CHARINDEX(CHAR(10), reverse(substring(@SQL3, @i, @len))) + 1
    PRINT substring(@SQL3, @i, @len)
    set @i      =  @i + @len
    set @len    =  @maxChunk
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this (using "Results to text"):

```
SELECT
ISNULL(smsp.definition, ssmsp.definition) AS [Definition]
FROM
sys.all_objects AS sp
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.sql_modules AS smsp ON smsp.object_id = sp.object_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.system_sql_modules AS ssmsp ON ssmsp.object_id = sp.object_id
WHERE
(sp.type = N'V' OR sp.type = N'P' OR sp.type = N'RF' OR sp.type=N'PC')and(sp.name=N'YourObjectName' and SCHEMA_NAME(sp.schema_id)=N'dbo')
```

- C: Check constraint
- D: Default constraint
- F: Foreign Key constraint
- L: Log
- P: Stored procedure
- PK: Primary Key constraint
- RF: Replication Filter stored procedure
- S: System table
- TR: Trigger
- U: User table
- UQ: Unique constraint
- V: View
- X: Extended stored procedure

Cheers,

Comment: Doesn't work for tables (and it was the main point of question).

Answer (score -1):

we can let the SQL to generate create table script by navigating as

Script Table as > CREATE To > New Query Editor Window

[image]