# Export entire database to .sql file using Entity

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm trying to add some functionality to an application I'm writing, where the user can create a new `Project`, which has it's own database. When this is done, the previous `Project` database is to be exported to a .sql file that I can import and review later. Problem is, I can't see a way to export it. I've tried looking for a method to do so using:

```
using (var context = new DBContext())
{
    context.Database. // no method here for export
}
```

Is there a way inside of entity to export the database to a .sql file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **No**. It is not possible to do that through `entity framework` since there are many DB objects such as `trigger` or `check constraint` and properties like `description` which are not captured by `EF`.

However, you can use other tools such as [SMO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)

Comment: No problem. I will look into the link now.

Comment: I'm still new to Entity and complex actions with databases as a whole, so forgive me if this is a silly question, but is it possible/feasible to use a stored procedure to do the export to a .sql file?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks It is Entity Framework not Entity :). I googled it and reached a couple of interesting solutions for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query