# How to generate create script of tables with their constraints using SQL query in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to generate create table script of already created table in my database.

I know we can generate scripts using right click on table and click on 'script table as'
menu and script will be generated. Because I want to execute this by **using SSIS package** so I need a generated script file of modified database.

I want to do same process using SQL query. is there any way??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query/16797460#16797460

Comment: @Devart.. thanx so much but is there any solution to get create scripts of all the tables of a database using single query, because I have to generate all the tables 300+.

Comment: Create cursor and executing query for every table. Another post: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/67b45a/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table/

Comment: When I execute above link query then O/P is like this.....[TRIGGER_NAME] VARCHAR(200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL , [TRIGGER_GROUP] VARCHAR(200) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL.....**What is COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS** I have no need of this how can I remove this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @object_id INT, @object_name SYSNAME

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY LOCAL FOR
    SELECT o.[object_id], '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
    FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE o.[type] = 'U'
        AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @object_id, @object_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    ;WITH index_column AS 
    (
        SELECT 
              ic.[object_id]
            , ic.index_id
            , ic.is_descending_key
            , ic.is_included_column
            , c.name
        FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
        WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
    ),
    fk_columns AS 
    (
         SELECT 
              k.constraint_object_id
            , cname = c.name
            , rcname = rc.name
        FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
        JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
        WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
    )
    SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
        SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
            CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
                THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
                ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                    CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                           THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                         WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                           THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                         WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                           THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                         WHEN tp.name = 'decimal' 
                           THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                        ELSE ''
                    END +
                    CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                    CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
                    CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END 
            END + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
        LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
        WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
        ORDER BY c.column_id
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
        + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                        (SELECT STUFF((
                             SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                             FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                             JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                             WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                                 AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                                 AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                             FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
                + ')' + CHAR(13)
                FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
                WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                    AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)
        + ISNULL((SELECT (
            SELECT CHAR(13) +
                 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' WITH' 
                + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                    THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                    ELSE ' CHECK' 
                  END + 
                  ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
                  + STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                    FROM fk_columns k
                    WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                   + ')' +
                  ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
                  + STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                    FROM fk_columns k
                    WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
                   + ')'
                + CASE 
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                    WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                    ELSE '' 
                  END
                + CASE 
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                    WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                    ELSE '' 
                  END 
                + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
            JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
            WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
            FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
        + ISNULL(((SELECT
             CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END 
                    + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON ' + @object_name + ' (' +
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                    FROM index_column c
                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                    + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                        STUFF((
                        SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
                        FROM index_column c
                        WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                            AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
                AND i.is_primary_key = 0
                AND i.[type] = 2
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
        ), '') + CHAR(13) + 'GO'

    PRINT @SQL

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @object_id, @object_name

END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Output -

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test1]
(
      [ID] INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_test1_ID] PRIMARY KEY ([ID] ASC)
)
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_name]
(
      [ID] INT NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_name_ID] PRIMARY KEY ([ID] ASC)
)
GO
```

Comment: @Devart...thanks a lot..u provide me nice solution for my doubt.thnkx..:)

Comment: If this solution fully suit you, please approve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this one:

```
declare @vsSQL varchar(8000)
declare @vsTableName varchar(50)
select @vsTableName = '<TABLENAME>'

select @vsSQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @vsTableName + char(10) + '(' + char(10)

select @vsSQL = @vsSQL + ' ' + sc.Name + ' ' +
st.Name +
case when st.Name in ('varchar','varchar','char','nchar') then '(' + cast(sc.Length as varchar) + ') ' else ' ' end +
case when sc.IsNullable = 1 then 'NULL' else 'NOT NULL' end + ',' + char(10)
from sysobjects so
join syscolumns sc on sc.id = so.id
join systypes st on st.xusertype = sc.xusertype
where so.name = @vsTableName
order by
sc.ColID

select substring(@vsSQL,1,len(@vsSQL) - 2) + char(10) + ')'
```

Comment: You can create a stored procedure of it and then execute it with <TABLENAME> as parameter.

Comment: Can you please tell me that if I execute this in **SQL Server Agent Jobs** then where is the output of this stored procedure will go, and can I use that output further into SQL Server Agent Job. help me out pls.