# Backup Remote SQL database by building SQL Generate Scripts

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a VB.net application with an MS SQL Backend. I want to be able to take a "Snapshot" of the remote database so that the database can be cloned to another location. I want to do this by building SQL generate scripts similar to those created by SQL Management Studio. I found this code:

[How to generate create script of tables with their constraints using SQL query in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884660/how-to-generate-create-script-of-tables-with-their-constraints-using-sql-query-i/20885267#20885267?newreg=ff4a74c57b594694afe8fc68969e1a20)

which prints the scripts to the Messages window in SQL Studio express but I need it returned as the result so I can call it from my .Net application and get the scripts back so I can save them to a text file, ready to recreate the database elsewhere. Can anyone help?

The next stage of this task is scripting, then inserting all the data from the "Live" database. I know I can do all this using the Script Tools in SQL Studio but I need it built into my application, so my users can clone their Network Database locally to use away from the network.

Comment: "I want to be able to take a "Snapshot" of the remote database so that the database can be cloned to another location" - a backup?

Comment: It is a sort of backup. I cannot create an Actual SQl backup (.bak) as the database will be on a different machine to the software that will be doing the "Backup". I think the only option I have is to build a "Generate Script" to rebuild the database instead of restoring a backup

Answer (score 0):

The Options if you don't want to sync the server editions.

- Upgrade the older version of SQL Server to be at the same level as the newer SQL Server.
- Script out the objects from the newer database and then usp a bcp process to extract the data from the newer database and import it into the older database.
- Use the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to build an SSIS package to move the data (it will move the data only).
- Build a custom SSIS package to do the data move.
- Use replication to move the data from the newer database to the older one.
- Use some other form of scripting, such as with PowerShell, to keep the databases in sync.

You should still want to use **compressed database backups**, you can then restore the database to end users with a smaller foot print. There are other options as well, like log shipping, database mirroring, and setting up availability groups. These all require more work than taking a compressed backup.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [Gigabits] TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\Gigabits.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'Gigabits-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO
```

[image]

[image]

**You cannot attach/detach or backup/restore a database from a newer version (SQL Server 2008 R2 - 10.50.1600) of SQL Server down to an older version (2008 - v10.00.1600)** - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility.

You can either get around this problem by

using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances

otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (Tasks > Generate Scripts) or using a third-party tool

or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's SQL Compare and SQL Data Compare to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.