# generate a create table statement for a given table in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this code that is about generating a create table. But, the code doesnt give primary keys.What can I do ?

```
select  'create table [' + so.name + '] (' + o.list + ')' + 
         CASE WHEN tc.Constraint_Name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'ALTER TABLE ' + 
         so.Name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + tc.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY ' +
         ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + ')'
        END
from    sysobjects so
cross apply
    (SELECT 
        '  ['+column_name+'] ' + 
        data_type + case data_type
            when 'sql_variant' then ''
            when 'text' then ''
            when 'ntext' then ''
            when 'xml' then ''
            when 'decimal' then '(' + cast(numeric_precision as varchar) 
                + ', ' + cast(numeric_scale as varchar) + ')'
            else coalesce('('+case when character_maximum_length = -1 then 'MAX' 
            else cast(character_maximum_length as varchar) end +')','') end + ' ' +
        case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=so.name
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
        ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(so.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(so.name) as varchar) + ')'
        else ''
        end + ' ' +
         (case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
          case when information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL 
        THEN 'DEFAULT '+ information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT 
        ELSE '' END + ', ' 

     from information_schema.columns where table_name = so.name
     order by ordinal_position
    FOR XML PATH('')) o (list)
left join
    information_schema.table_constraints tc
on  tc.Table_name       = so.Name
AND tc.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'
cross apply
    (select '[' + Column_Name + '], '
     FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     WHERE  kcu.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name
     ORDER BY
        ORDINAL_POSITION
     FOR XML PATH('')) j (list)
where   xtype = 'U'
AND name    NOT IN ('dtproperties')
```

Example : 
When code rus,output :

```
create table [ScrapReason] (  [Name] nvarchar(50)  NOT NULL , 
             [ModifiedDate] datetime  NOT NULL DEFAULT (getdate()), )
ALTER TABLE ScrapReason ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ScrapReason_ScrapReasonID PRIMARY KEY  ([ScrapReasonID])
```

There is no primary key in create table statement.

Comment: ..... are you creating table scripts like this? what is your requirement to do it like this instead of many many many simpler methods?

Comment: What are simpler methods?

Comment: In SSMS just right click table and create script

Comment: I know SSMS right click, but ı have to creat scripts by using codes.

Answer (score 1):

Use this SQL Script OR Refer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16797460/3198474

```
         DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
SELECT @table_name = 'dbo.Emp1'

DECLARE 
      @object_name SYSNAME
    , @object_id INT

SELECT 
      @object_name = '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
    , @object_id = o.[object_id]
FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE s.name + '.' + o.name = @table_name
    AND o.[type] = 'U'
    AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

;WITH index_column AS 
(
    SELECT 
          ic.[object_id]
        , ic.index_id
        , ic.is_descending_key
        , ic.is_included_column
        , c.name
    FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
),
fk_columns AS 
(
     SELECT 
          k.constraint_object_id
        , cname = c.name
        , rcname = rc.name
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
    JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
)
SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
            THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
            ELSE UPPER(tp.name) + 
                CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary', 'text')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar', 'ntext')
                       THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                     WHEN tp.name = 'decimal' 
                       THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                    ELSE ''
                END +
                CASE WHEN c.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN ' COLLATE ' + c.collation_name ELSE '' END +
                CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END + 
                CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END 
        END + CHAR(13)
    FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
    WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
    ORDER BY c.column_id
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
    + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY (' + 
                    (SELECT STUFF((
                         SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                         FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                         JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                         WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                             AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                             AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
            + ')' + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)
    + ISNULL((SELECT (
        SELECT CHAR(13) +
             'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' WITH' 
            + CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted = 1 
                THEN ' NOCHECK' 
                ELSE ' CHECK' 
              END + 
              ' ADD CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + '] FOREIGN KEY(' 
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.cname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')' +
              ' REFERENCES [' + SCHEMA_NAME(ro.[schema_id]) + '].[' + ro.name + '] ('
              + STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + k.rcname + ']'
                FROM fk_columns k
                WHERE k.constraint_object_id = fk.[object_id]
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
               + ')'
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON DELETE CASCADE' 
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON DELETE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.delete_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON DELETE SET DEFAULT' 
                ELSE '' 
              END
            + CASE 
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 1 THEN ' ON UPDATE CASCADE'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 2 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET NULL'
                WHEN fk.update_referential_action = 3 THEN ' ON UPDATE SET DEFAULT'  
                ELSE '' 
              END 
            + CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE ' + @object_name + ' CHECK CONSTRAINT [' + fk.name  + ']' + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.foreign_keys fk WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.objects ro WITH (NOWAIT) ON ro.[object_id] = fk.referenced_object_id
        WHERE fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
        FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')), '')
    + ISNULL(((SELECT
         CHAR(13) + 'CREATE' + CASE WHEN i.is_unique = 1 THEN ' UNIQUE' ELSE '' END 
                + ' NONCLUSTERED INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON ' + @object_name + ' (' +
                STUFF((
                SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']' + CASE WHEN c.is_descending_key = 1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END
                FROM index_column c
                WHERE c.is_included_column = 0
                    AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')'  
                + ISNULL(CHAR(13) + 'INCLUDE (' + 
                    STUFF((
                    SELECT ', [' + c.name + ']'
                    FROM index_column c
                    WHERE c.is_included_column = 1
                        AND c.index_id = i.index_id
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '') + ')', '')  + CHAR(13)
        FROM sys.indexes i WITH (NOWAIT)
        WHERE i.[object_id] = @object_id
            AND i.is_primary_key = 0
            AND i.[type] = 2
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ), '')
IF(ISNULL(@SQL,'') ='')
BEGIN
    Print @table_name + ' does not exists'
END
ELSE
Begin
PRINT @SQL
End
```

Comment: +Many for using the system catalog views as is correct in SQL Server and avoiding `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.

Comment: Can I omit PRINT @SQL statement?

Comment: its up to you what you want to do with the generated script; want to print or execute

Comment: There is no error.When I made it execute, output was Command(s) completed successfully. But there are no create table statement etc.

Comment: I added PRINT @SQL but,there is no change :(

Comment: then i think you forgot to change the parameter value, please change and pass the table name which exists in your Database see at the top @table_name = 'dbo.Emp'

Comment: I did but I will try again.

Comment: Hi Naveen Kumar! Your code is working now.Thank you very much :)