# How to use the option "Generate SQL script" for a table using a query in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I want to get script for creating table. Now I use "Right Click - All task- Generate SQL Script" to create this script. How to make this action using a query? Existing solutions isn't suitable for me because it works only in SQL Server 2005 or later.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post what you have done so far, (the codes that does not work for you) and the error you get

Comment: @Ormoz, for example, when I use query in this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query) query analyzer return me errors:
Line 17: Incorrect syntax near 'MAX'.
Line 30: Incorrect syntax near ','.
Line 69:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
Line 78: Incorrect syntax near 'XML'.
Line 95: Incorrect syntax near 'XML'.
Line 102:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FOR'.
Line 144:Must declare the variable '@SQL'.

Comment: This is work with.net code. If you are using sql management studio. And you can access this functions in Microsoft.sqlserver.management assembly