# How I can get table definition in SQL SERVER 2008 R2 using SQL query?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a sample java program in which I get the definition of all objects like views, triggers, functions, etc. using the  following queries:-

```
select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects where type='V'; //for Views
select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects where type='TF'; //for Functions
select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects where type='TR'; //for Triggers
select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects where type='P'; //for Stored Procedures
```

But the following query doesn't work to get ddl(table definition) for tables:-

```
select object_definition(object_id) from sys.objects where type='U'; //for User defined Tables
```

Right now I am using the solutions given here:   [Generate SQL Create Scripts for existing tables with Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query) 
and [How to Generate a CREATE TABLE Script For an Existing Table: Part 1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/67b45a/how-to-generate-a-create-table-script-for-an-existing-table/)

Is there any direct sql query using which I can get the Table definition.

Comment: why don't you try short cut key `ALT+F1` to see table definition?

Comment: @curiousguy I have to get ddl in a java program using sql query.

Comment: why don't you try `sp_help 'tablename'` ?

Comment: @curiousguy I have already tried this and it also doesn't give the exact create script like the GET_DDL Method in Oracle. If possible, I don't want to create the scripts manually using java program which I am doing right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look on

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, we only get the Database Name, Table Name, Table Type and Table Schema and Table Schema does not contain the create script for the table. 
Using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS also doesn't give the create script for table.

Answer (score 1):

I found this (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/script-table-definitions-using-tsql/) by Tim Chapman and did some formatting and small modifications:

The call is as easy as

```
SELECT dbo.CreateScriptTable( 'YourTable',1,1,'NewName',0)
```

Try it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CreateScriptTable (
@TableName SYSNAME,
@IncludeConstraints BIT = 1,
@IncludeIndexes BIT = 1,
@NewTableName SYSNAME = NULL,
@UseSystemDataTypes BIT = 0 
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @MainDefinition TABLE(FieldValue VARCHAR(200));     
     DECLARE @DBName SYSNAME;     
     DECLARE @ClusteredPK BIT;     
     DECLARE @TableSchema NVARCHAR(255);
     SET @DBName = DB_NAME(DB_ID());
     SELECT @TableName = name FROM sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName);     
     DECLARE @ShowFields TABLE(FieldID INT IDENTITY(1,1),DatabaseName VARCHAR(100),TableOwner VARCHAR(100),TableName VARCHAR(100),FieldName VARCHAR(100),
                               ColumnPosition INT,ColumnDefaultValue VARCHAR(100),ColumnDefaultName VARCHAR(100),IsNullable BIT,DataType VARCHAR(100),MaxLength INT,
                               NumericPrecision INT,NumericScale INT,DomainName VARCHAR(100),FieldListingName VARCHAR(110),FieldDefinition CHAR(1),IdentityColumn BIT,
                               IdentitySeed INT,IdentityIncrement INT,IsCharColumn BIT);
    DECLARE @HoldingArea TABLE(FldID SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1),Flds VARCHAR(4000),FldValue CHAR(1) DEFAULT(0));
    DECLARE @PKObjectID TABLE(ObjectID INT);
    DECLARE @Uniques TABLE(ObjectID INT);
    DECLARE @HoldingAreaValues TABLE(FldID SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1),Flds VARCHAR(4000),FldValue CHAR(1) DEFAULT(0));
    DECLARE @Definition TABLE(DefinitionID SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1),FieldValue VARCHAR(200));

    INSERT INTO @ShowFields(DatabaseName,TableOwner,TableName,FieldName,ColumnPosition,ColumnDefaultValue,ColumnDefaultName,IsNullable,
                            DataType,MaxLength,NumericPrecision,NumericScale,DomainName,
                            FieldListingName,FieldDefinition,IdentityColumn,IdentitySeed,
                            IdentityIncrement,IsCharColumn)
         SELECT DB_NAME(),TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CAST(ORDINAL_POSITION AS INT),COLUMN_DEFAULT,dobj.name AS ColumnDefaultName,
                CASE WHEN c.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,DATA_TYPE,CAST(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS INT),CAST(NUMERIC_PRECISION AS INT),CAST(NUMERIC_SCALE AS INT),
                DOMAIN_NAME,COLUMN_NAME + ',','' AS FieldDefinition,CASE WHEN ic.object_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IdentityColumn,CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value,0) AS INT) AS IdentitySeed,
                CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value,0) AS INT) AS IdentityIncrement,CASE WHEN st.collation_name IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsCharColumn     
         FROM         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c         JOIN sys.columns sc ON  c.TABLE_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id) AND c.COLUMN_NAME = sc.Name         
         LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic ON c.TABLE_NAME = OBJECT_NAME(ic.object_id) AND c.COLUMN_NAME = ic.Name
         JOIN sys.types st ON COALESCE(c.DOMAIN_NAME,c.DATA_TYPE) = st.name
         LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects dobj ON dobj.object_id = sc.default_object_id AND dobj.type = 'D'
         WHERE c.TABLE_NAME = @TableName     
         ORDER BY c.TABLE_NAME, c.ORDINAL_POSITION;

    SELECT TOP 1 @TableSchema = TableOwner FROM @ShowFields;

    INSERT INTO @HoldingArea (Flds) VALUES('(');
    INSERT INTO @Definition(FieldValue) VALUES('CREATE TABLE ' + CASE WHEN @NewTableName IS NOT NULL THEN @NewTableName ELSE @DBName + '.' + @TableSchema + '.' + @TableName END);
    INSERT INTO @Definition(FieldValue) VALUES('(');

    INSERT INTO @Definition(FieldValue)
    SELECT FieldName + ' ' + CASE WHEN DomainName IS NOT NULL AND @UseSystemDataTypes = 0 
                                             THEN DomainName + CASE WHEN IsNullable = 1 
                                                                    THEN ' NULL ' 
                                                                    ELSE ' NOT NULL ' 
                                                                END 
                                             ELSE UPPER(DataType) + CASE WHEN IsCharColumn = 1 
                                                                         THEN '(' + CAST(MaxLength AS VARCHAR(10)) + ')' 
                                                                         ELSE '' 
                                                                    END + CASE WHEN IdentityColumn = 1 
                                                                               THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(IdentitySeed AS VARCHAR(5))+ ',' + CAST(IdentityIncrement AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')' 
                                                                               ELSE '' 
                                                                          END + CASE WHEN IsNullable = 1 
                                                                                     THEN ' NULL ' 
                                                                                     ELSE ' NOT NULL ' 
                                                                                END + CASE WHEN ColumnDefaultName IS NOT NULL AND @IncludeConstraints = 1 
                                                                                           THEN 'CONSTRAINT [' + ColumnDefaultName + '] DEFAULT' + UPPER(ColumnDefaultValue) 
                                                                                           ELSE '' 
                                                                                      END
                                             END + CASE WHEN FieldID = (SELECT MAX(FieldID) FROM @ShowFields) 
                                                        THEN '' 
                                                        ELSE ',' END
    FROM @ShowFields;

    IF @IncludeConstraints = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Definition(FieldValue)
        SELECT ',CONSTRAINT [' + name + '] FOREIGN KEY (' + ParentColumns + ') REFERENCES [' + ReferencedObject + '](' + ReferencedColumns + ')'
        FROM (SELECT ReferencedObject = OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id), ParentObject = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id),fk.name,REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE((SELECT cp.name + ','
                                                                                                                                                              FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                                                                                                                                                              JOIN sys.columns cp ON fkc.parent_object_id = cp.object_id AND fkc.parent_column_id = cp.column_id
                                                                                                                                                              WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
                                                                                                                                                              FOR XML PATH(''))), 2, 8000)) ParentColumns,
                                                                                                                                   REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE((SELECT cr.name + ','
                                                                                                                                                              FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
                                                                                                                                                              JOIN sys.columns cr ON fkc.referenced_object_id = cr.object_id AND fkc.referenced_column_id = cr.column_id
                                                                                                                                                              WHERE fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
                                                                                                                                                              FOR XML PATH(''))), 2, 8000)) ReferencedColumns
              FROM sys.foreign_keys fk) a
              WHERE ParentObject = @TableName;

              INSERT INTO @Definition(FieldValue)
              SELECT',CONSTRAINT [' + name + '] CHECK ' + definition FROM sys.check_constraints
              WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = @TableName;

              INSERT INTO @PKObjectID(ObjectID)
              SELECT DISTINCT PKObject = cco.object_id
              FROM sys.key_constraints cco
              JOIN sys.index_columns cc ON cco.parent_object_id = cc.object_id AND cco.unique_index_id = cc.index_id
              JOIN sys.indexes i ON cc.object_id = i.object_id AND cc.index_id = i.index_id
              WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = @TableName AND i.type = 1 AND is_primary_key = 1;

              INSERT INTO @Uniques(ObjectID)
              SELECT DISTINCT PKObject = cco.object_id 
              FROM sys.key_constraints cco
              JOIN sys.index_columns cc ON cco.parent_object_id = cc.object_id AND cco.unique_index_id = cc.index_id
              JOIN sys.indexes i ON cc.object_id = i.object_id AND cc.index_id = i.index_id
              WHERE OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = @TableName AND i.type = 2 AND is_primary_key = 0 AND is_unique_constraint = 1;

              SET @ClusteredPK = CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;

              INSERT INTO @Definition(FieldValue)
              SELECT ',CONSTRAINT ' + name + CASE type WHEN 'PK' 
                                                       THEN ' PRIMARY KEY ' + CASE WHEN pk.ObjectID IS NULL 
                                                                                   THEN ' NONCLUSTERED ' 
                                                                                   ELSE ' CLUSTERED ' 
                                                                               END
                                                       WHEN 'UQ' 
                                                       THEN ' UNIQUE ' END + CASE WHEN u.ObjectID IS NOT NULL 
                                                                                  THEN ' NONCLUSTERED ' 
                                                                                  ELSE '' 
                                                                              END 
                    + '(' +  REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE((SELECT c.name +  + CASE WHEN cc.is_descending_key = 1 
                                                                               THEN ' DESC' 
                                                                               ELSE ' ASC' 
                                                                               END + ','             
                                                        FROM sys.key_constraints ccok
                                                        LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns cc ON ccok.parent_object_id = cc.object_id AND cco.unique_index_id = cc.index_id
                                                        LEFT JOIN sys.columns c ON cc.object_id = c.object_id AND cc.column_id = c.column_id
                                                        LEFT JOIN sys.indexes i ON cc.object_id = i.object_id AND cc.index_id = i.index_id
                                                        WHERE i.object_id = ccok.parent_object_id AND ccok.object_id = cco.object_id
                                                        FOR XML PATH(''))), 2, 8000)) + ')'
             FROM sys.key_constraints cco
             LEFT JOIN @PKObjectID pk ON cco.object_id = pk.ObjectID
             LEFT JOIN @Uniques u ON cco.object_id = u.objectID
             WHERE OBJECT_NAME(cco.parent_object_id) = @TableName
    END

    INSERT INTO @Definition(FieldValue) VALUES(');');

    IF @IncludeIndexes = 1
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @Definition(FieldValue)
        SELECT 'CREATE ' + type_desc + ' INDEX [' + [name] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + '] ON [' +  OBJECT_NAME(object_id) + '] (' + REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(( SELECT name + CASE WHEN sc.is_descending_key = 1 
                                                                                                                                                                                              THEN ' DESC' 
                                                                                                                                                                                              ELSE ' ASC' 
                                                                                                                                                                                          END + ','
                                                                                                                                                                           FROM sys.index_columns sc
                                                                                                                                                                           JOIN sys.columns c ON sc.object_id = c.object_id AND sc.column_id = c.column_id
                                                                                                                                                                           WHERE OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id) = @TableName AND sc.object_id = i.object_id AND sc.index_id = i.index_id
                                                                                                                                                                           ORDER BY index_column_id ASC
                                                                                                                                                                           FOR XML PATH(''))), 2, 8000)) + ');'
        FROM sys.indexes i
        WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = @TableName;
    END

    RETURN
    (
     SELECT STUFF
    (
        (SELECT CHAR(10) + FieldValue
        FROM @Definition
        FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
    );
END
GO
```

Comment: You should have a look to the link I provided in my answer and there to the user comments ... There are some flaws users found. Might be important for you...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have already created a query for this according to my requirement using the solution given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query and it works for me.