# Sybase : How I can get table definition using query?

Tags: sybase, ddl

I want to generate create table script in Sybase Central. I used: 
`SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`
It gives information in table format and I don't need this kind of format and info.
And I also don't want to use ddlgen command.

I found the same script in SQL (answered by *@Shnugo*):

[How I can get table definition in SQL SERVER 2008 R2 using SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177493/how-i-can-get-table-definition-in-sql-server-2008-r2-using-sql-query) 
I searched all where but cannot get any script like this. I don't want to create same as sql in sybase, as I am doing it right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK thanx I got the answer :
There is a procedure which fetch the all tables' ddl in database:

```
use sybsystemprocs
go

if object_id('dbo.sp_ddl_create_table') is not null
    drop procedure sp_ddl_create_table
    print "Dropping sp_ddl_create_table"
go

create proc sp_ddl_create_table
as

-- Creates the DDL for all the user tables in the
-- current database

select  right('create table ' + so1.name + '(' + '
', 255 * ( abs( sign(sc1.colid - 1) - 1 ) ) )+
        sc1.name + ' ' +
        st1.name + ' ' +
        substring( '(' + rtrim( convert( char, sc1.length ) ) + ') ', 1,
        patindex('%char', st1.name ) * 10 ) +
        substring( '(' + rtrim( convert( char, sc1.prec ) ) + ', ' + rtrim(
        convert( char, sc1.scale ) ) + ') ' , 1, patindex('numeric', st1.name ) * 10 ) +
        substring( 'NOT NULL', ( convert( int, convert( bit,( sc1.status & 8 ) ) ) * 4 ) + 1,
        8 * abs(convert(bit, (sc1.status & 0x80)) - 1 ) ) +
        right('identity ', 9 * convert(bit, (sc1.status & 0x80)) ) +
        right(',', 5 * ( convert(int,sc2.colid) - convert(int,sc1.colid) ) ) +
        right(' )
' + 'go' + '
' + '
', 255 * abs( sign( ( convert(int,sc2.colid) - convert(int,sc1.colid) ) ) -
1 ) )
from    sysobjects so1,
        syscolumns sc1,
        syscolumns sc2,
        systypes st1
where so1.type = 'U'
and sc1.id = so1.id
and st1.usertype = sc1.usertype
and sc2.id = sc1.id
and sc2.colid = (select max(colid)
                from syscolumns
                where id = sc1.id)
order by so1.name, sc1.colid
go

if object_id('dbo.sp_ddl_create_table') is not null
begin
    grant execute on sp_ddl_create_table to public
    print "Created sp_ddl_create_table"
end
else
    print "Failed to create sp_ddl_create_table"
go

go
```