# MS SQL script generating different DDL on different machine

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

We are working on MS SQL database to backup the ddl of database tables. We have written below script to generate ddl from MS SQL referred from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query) . Script to generate DDL is :

```
DECLARE @table_name SYSNAME
        SELECT @table_name = 'dbo.deal'
        DECLARE 
              @object_name SYSNAME
            , @object_id INT
        SELECT 
              @object_name = '[' + s.name + '].[' + o.name + ']'
            , @object_id = o.[object_id]
        FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
        JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
        WHERE s.name + '.' + o.name = @table_name
            AND o.[type] = 'U'
            AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0

        DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

        ;WITH index_column AS 
        (
            SELECT 
                  ic.[object_id]
                , ic.index_id
                , ic.is_descending_key
                , ic.is_included_column
                , c.name
            FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
            JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON ic.[object_id] = c.[object_id] AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
            WHERE ic.[object_id] = @object_id
        ),
        fk_columns AS 
        (
             SELECT 
                  k.constraint_object_id
                , cname = c.name
                , rcname = rc.name
            FROM sys.foreign_key_columns k WITH (NOWAIT)
            JOIN sys.columns rc WITH (NOWAIT) ON rc.[object_id] = k.referenced_object_id AND rc.column_id = k.referenced_column_id 
            JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = k.parent_column_id
            WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id
        )
        SELECT @SQL = 'CREATE TABLE ' + @object_name + CHAR(13) + '(' + CHAR(13) + STUFF((
            SELECT CHAR(9) + ', [' + c.name + '] ' + 
                CASE WHEN c.is_computed = 1
                    THEN 'AS ' + cc.[definition] 
                    ELSE '[' + tp.name + ']' + 
                        CASE WHEN tp.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'varbinary', 'binary')
                               THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                             WHEN tp.name IN ('nvarchar', 'nchar')
                               THEN '(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(5)) END + ')'
                             WHEN tp.name IN ('datetime2', 'time2', 'datetimeoffset') 
                               THEN '(' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                             WHEN tp.name IN ('decimal','numeric') 
                               THEN '(' + CAST(c.[precision] AS VARCHAR(5)) + ',' + CAST(c.scale AS VARCHAR(5)) + ')'
                            ELSE ''
                        END +  
                        CASE WHEN ic.is_identity = 1 THEN ' IDENTITY(' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.seed_value, '0') AS CHAR(1)) + ',' + CAST(ISNULL(ic.increment_value, '1') AS CHAR(1)) + ')' ELSE '' END + 
                        CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ' NULL' ELSE ' NOT NULL' END +
                        CASE WHEN dc.[definition] IS NOT NULL THEN ' DEFAULT' + dc.[definition] ELSE '' END                
                END + CHAR(13)
            FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
            JOIN sys.types tp WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.user_type_id = tp.user_type_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.computed_columns cc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = cc.[object_id] AND c.column_id = cc.column_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints dc WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.default_object_id != 0 AND c.[object_id] = dc.parent_object_id AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id
            LEFT JOIN sys.identity_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.is_identity = 1 AND c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
            WHERE c.[object_id] = @object_id
            ORDER BY c.column_id
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, CHAR(9) + ' ')
            + ISNULL((SELECT CHAR(9) + ', CONSTRAINT [' + k.name + '] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (' + 
                            (SELECT STUFF((
                                 SELECT ', [' + c.name + '] ' + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN 'DESC' ELSE 'ASC' END
                                 FROM sys.index_columns ic WITH (NOWAIT)
                                 JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT) ON c.[object_id] = ic.[object_id] AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
                                 WHERE ic.is_included_column = 0
                                     AND ic.[object_id] = k.parent_object_id 
                                     AND ic.index_id = k.unique_index_id     
                                 FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''))
                    + ')' + CHAR(13)
                    FROM sys.key_constraints k WITH (NOWAIT)
                    WHERE k.parent_object_id = @object_id 
                        AND k.[type] = 'PK'), '') + ')'  + CHAR(13)

        PRINT @SQL; SELECT @SQL;
```

Now we are getting issue with this script.

This working fine with **Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64) Service Pack 2**. But with **SQL server 11.0.6523 (2012)** version, it missing one column from table.

Same query script generating different result for different version of SQL Server.

*DDL Script generated from SQL Server Management studio is* :

```
USE [DealTrackPF]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[deal](
    [deal_id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [cl_id] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [st_id] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [sec_id] [int] NULL,
    [desc] [varchar](400) NULL,
    [date_added] [datetime] NULL,
    [deal_number_old] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [st_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [p_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [remarks] [varchar](2000) NULL,
    [desi_id] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    **[deal_number] [numeric](18, 0) NULL**,
    [x_no] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [pro_id] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [u_revenue] [money] NULL,
    [r_fee] [money] NULL,
    [my_points] [numeric](5, 2) NULL,
    [dms_deal_number] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [assignee] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [last_updated] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [pf_deal] [int] NULL,
    [email_sent] [datetime] NULL,
    [com_id] [int] NULL,
    [c_approval] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[deal] ADD [my_contacts] [varchar](200) NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[deal] ADD [my_status] [varchar](50) NULL
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[deal] ADD [r_ex] [int] NULL
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[deal] ADD [r_exceeds] [int] NULL
CONSTRAINT [PK_DEAL] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [deal_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

When running script on above ddl on SQL server SP3 11.0.6523 2012, it skipping **deal_number** column.

What can be the cause of skipping some column using the script given above for different database versions on different machine?