# c# program as a .NET SQLCLR stored procedure rewrite

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlclr, smo

I am using Visual Studio 2015 & SQL Server 2014. I have the below C# program for which I have to pass the Table object name and the program generates the Create Table script. Now I am working on writing this as a SQLCLR Stored Procedure. Could you please give me an idea or direction to accomplish this?

```cs
public class CSHProgram
    {      
        static void Main()
        {
            Server dbservername = new Server(@"(local)");
            string tablename = "";

            try
            {
                dbservername.ConnectionContext.LoginSecure = true;
                savetbldeftofile(dbservername, tablename);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (dbservername.ConnectionContext.IsOpen)
                    dbservername.ConnectionContext.Disconnect();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        public static void savetbldeftofile(Server dbservername, string tablename)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            string tblName = @"\b" + tablename + "\b";

            foreach (Database DBServer in dbservername.Databases)
            {
                Match db = Regex.Match(DBServer.Name, "UserTestDB", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                if (db.Success)
                {
                    foreach (Table dbTbl in DBServer.Tables)
                    {
                        Match tabl = Regex.Match(dbTbl.Name, tblName, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        if (tabl.Success)
                        {
                            ScriptingOptions soptions = new ScriptingOptions();
                            soptions.ClusteredIndexes = true;
                            soptions.Default = true;
                            soptions.DriAll = true;
                            soptions.Indexes = true;
                            soptions.IncludeHeaders = true;
                            soptions.AppendToFile = true;

                            StringCollection SCollection = dbTbl.Script(soptions);
                            foreach (string str in SCollection)
                            {
                                sb.Append(str);
                                sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                            }
                        }

                        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@"c:\temp\" + tablename + ".sql");
                        sw.Write(sb.ToString());
                        sw.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How would I pass the result of the above C# program to the .NET SQLCLR stored procedure below?

```
public static void Scriptfile (string table)
{
    SqlPipe Procedure = SqlContext.Pipe;
    Procedure.Send("");
}
```

Comment: The following post from Devart is an excellent example on how to generate the Create T-SQL script from an existing table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by:

> pass the result of the above C# program to the .NET SQLCLR stored procedure

The code for the console app you have at the moment cannot be placed within a SQLCLR assembly and work as you are using SMO and that is specifically disabled within SQL Server's CLR host.

Generally speaking, you pass values into a SQLCLR object via input parameters, just like a T-SQL stored procedure or function.

Technically, you *can* keep the SMO code working in the console app and call that .EXE as an external process via `Process.Start()` within the SQLCLR object, but that requires:

1. Setting your assembly to `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`,

   and
2. setting this up to use a work-flow similar to:

   1. create a tempfile name in the SQLCLR code (so that concurrently running processes don't accidentally share the same file) using [Path.GetTempFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)
   2. call the console app, passing in the tempfile name
   3. read the tempfile in the SQLCLR object into a string variable
   4. delete the tempfile (i.e. cleanup)
   5. return the string variable as an `out` parameter

I'm not sure that it's worth the trouble to do all of that, but that is what it would take to accomplish.

Comment: Well, I am trying to script out Create Table by passing the name of the table in the C# Console App but I want to do this in SQL Server. That was the reason why I went down the path of .net SQL CLR Stored Procedure. Is there a better way to accomplish this. "pass the result of the above C# program to the .NET SQLCLR stored procedure" I actually meant if there was a way to send the results of savetbldeftofile() function in the .net SQL CLR Stored Procedure. If there's no other best way to accomplish this I will follow your work-flow.

Comment: @user25407 No, there is absolutely no way to use the `SMO` class within SQLCLR. So if you simply must initiate this from a T-SQL stored procedure or function, then you need to run the .EXE as an external process, which will save to a file, and then you read the file. I will update my answer to include deleting the tempfile for cleanup.