# Create a SQL Server CREATE TABLE statement using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, azure, server, external-tables

The creation of a SQL Server External Table requires remote tables to be made accessible by running code of the following format on the local database:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [TABLE_NAME]
(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [int] NULL,
)
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = [EXTERNAL_DB_NAME])
```

I have a quite a few external tables to work with, and am wondering if this functionality can be automated. So, is there a way to create the text for a CREATE TABLE statement from the Information Schema views on the remote database ? This could then be altered and used to populate a dynamic query to be run on the local database.

Comment: Have a look into `dynamic sql`.

Comment: I will be using dynamic sql on the local database, but wondered if there was a way of grabbing the "CREATE TABLE.." code for a table via T-SQL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query

Comment: That's great thanks !