# How to export data in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to export SQL Server 2017 database; can anyone please help me where I can find this?

Comment: I need to export data structure of database, i am not able to find where i can do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get sql query script by table name in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905253/how-can-i-get-sql-query-script-by-table-name-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on a database ► Tasks ► Generate Scripts...
Select `Script entire database and all database objects`. `Next` like there is no tomorrow.
If you would like to include data as well, on the second step there is `Advanced` button. Find `Types of data to script`, then you can include data to schema as well. But there are more efficient ways to copy data exist.

[image]