# How to get dynamically generated CREATE statement with SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In MySQL you can do `SELECT CREATE TABLE` .... and it will return the `CREATE` statement that was used to create this table. I need to do the same in SQL Server.

Is there any similar functionality in SQL Server? I have a table name `test_table`.

I need to run a `SELECT` statement that would return the `CREATE TABLE` string that was used to create this table. I tried this but it didn't work. How can I achieve this result in SQL Server?

Comment: short answer - there is no equivalent.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate SQL Create Scripts for existing tables with Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query)

Comment: For MySQL it's `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and **not** `SELECT CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 0):

You could try SELECT INTO and specify the name of a temporary table (prefixed with #).  It also works with physical tables (although I've not found a use for this).  Something like this

```
select '123' as colName into #newTable;

select * from #newTable;
```

```
colName
123
```

Comment: thank you. how does this help generate the CREATE statement? Should I use `select create test_table as colName into #newTable` ?

Comment: You could use `select 123 as colName into test_table` and it would create the table

Comment: From SQL Server Management Studio, can you view Object Explorer Details, then select all of the tables you want, right click and generate Create Table scripts to new query editor window, or file.

Comment: I found [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5699/auto-generate-create-table-script-based-on-sql-server-query/) which might be interesting.