# How to generate a script to create all tables with different schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, replicate

I have about 200 tables in a schema.

I need to replicate these tables in a new backup schema with an automatic procedure.

I would like to create a procedure to dynamically recreate all the Tables in a Schema (potentially dynamic number of tables and columns) on a different schema.

I can cycle all the tables and create the `SELECT * INTO dbo_b.TABLE FROM dbo.TABLE` statement, but I get the error:

> Column 'AMBIENTE' has a data type that cannot participate in a columnstore index.

I created a view that simply `SELECT * FROM TABLE`, and tried to perform the `SELECT * INTO dbo_b.TABLE from dbo.VIEW` but I got the same issue.

It works only if I create the dbo_b.Table and INSERT INTO it: so I would need to generate a script to automatically cycle all the tables in my schema and generate a script to create the tables in the new schema.

It's not a one time job, it should run every day so I cannot do it manually.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different tools.)

Comment: Synapse through SQL Server management Studio 2019

Comment: Have you searched Stack Overflow? eg [generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706664/generate-sql-create-scripts-for-existing-tables-with-query)

Comment: Tried this by gave me an error "Incorrect syntax near FOR"

Comment: Can't help you with that as I'm sure the parser is correct! However I've used those scripts successfully to migrate hundreds of tables from one database to another.

Comment: Perhaps you and power83 can collaborate on addressing the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69395725/sel-server-select-into-msg-35343). "Backup" implies to me that you need a source control system and a development process that will capture whatever schema changes you make over time. The <select ... into ...> approach will never capture all the important attributes of a table (permissions, compress, constraints, triggers, filegroup, indexes, etc.)

Comment: You can try SELECT * INTO dbo_b.TABLE FROM dbo.TABLE WITH ( HEAP );

Answer (score 1):

Seams we get the same issue.

You can try to loop on all table and create table in the new schema in this way:

```
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YYYY' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'XXXX') 
 drop table [ZZZZ].[YYYY]  

CREATE TABLE [ZZZZ].[YYYY] 
WITH ( DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
,    HEAP ) as  
( SELECT * FROM XXXX.YYYY )
```

Let me know. BR

Comment: This worked lika a charm! Thank you @power83!