# Way to get the CREATE statement of global temporary table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have stored procedures I need to rewrite that used global temporary tables but now must use local temporary tables so that there is no cross over between users/the prod and dev db which are on the same SQL Server instances or any other new databases this database will be share the instance with.

I have to convert a lot of code that is like this

```
EXEC sp_executesql 
     N'SELECT manyDynamicallyCreatedColumns INTO ##someTempTable
```

I now for this to work for local tables I must instead create the table first and then `INSERT INTO` like

```
CREATE TABLE #tempTable (manyColumns);

EXEC sp_executesql 
     N'INSERT INTO #tempTable SELECT manyColumns FROM somewhere'
```

The issue I face is that this stored procedure has 8 different scenarios that lead to the global temp table. The select statement of the SQL is dynamically generated via a number of other queries. I think what would be the easiest way for me to figure out what my `CREATE TABLE #tempTable` should look like is if I could print/select what global temporary table looks like after it is made, for each of these 8 scenarios. Then I would just need a If/Else If statement that creates the local table appropriately before proceeding. But I don't know how or if this is possible.

For real tables I can right click -> Script to...-> Create.  I don't know if there is an analogous way to do this via scripting that works for global temporary tables. Is there?

Comment: I would politely suggest that the problem to be solved here isn't global vs local temp tables, it's the reliance on either of those to solve problems at all. You have a swiss-army-knife stored procedure that's doing 8 (apparently) very different jobs. Maybe it's time to properly design a solution rather than to to perpetuate mistakes?

Comment: It's the same job, its for 8 different products but its the same semantic business logic.  It's just some products have more columns than others.  Sure I could split them into 8 - but I would still need to know what this table is and looks like so I can make an analogous temporary local table or table type, or even if I have to convert to my application script - I need to know datatypes and column types so I can make an appropriate dataset structure.

Comment: I was able to accomplish this using the script from this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16797460/15414963