# SQLAlchemy Only Returns List Line if there are Carriage Returns in the Row (SQL Server)

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have an SQL query that generates the DDL to create tables based on the existing schema. I am running this to copy the schema to another database for backup purposes. I do not have permission to do it the normal way in SQL Server, so I'm using this other way.

Here is the DDL text that my query should return (and I have verified that the query returns in SSMS); it is only one row (and column) with the header name "DDL":

```
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
IF OBJECT_ID('[<schema_name>].[<table_name>]','SN') IS NOT NULL DROP SYNONYM [<schema_name>].[<table_name>];
IF OBJECT_ID('[<schema_name>].[<table_name>]','U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE [<schema_name>].[<table_name>];
RAISERROR('CREATE TABLE %s',10,1, '[<schema_name>].[<table_name>]') WITH NOWAIT;

CREATE TABLE [<schema_name>].[<table_name>] (
 ... column definitions ...
)  
RAISERROR('CREATING INDEXES OF  %s',10,1, '[<schema_name>].[<table_name>]') WITH NOWAIT;
```

However, sqlachemy only returns the last line:

```
RAISERROR('CREATING INDEXES OF  %s',10,1, '[<schema_name>].[<table_name>]') WITH NOWAIT;
```

And here's the python code around where this is pulled:

```
def get_create_ddls(table_name_list: list, conn) -> list:
    fd = open('CreateCreateDDL.sql', 'r')
    original_query = fd.read()
    fd.close()

    return_list = []
    for name in table_name_list:
        # prefixed the views as "V_"
        isView = name[:2] == "V_"

        if isView:
            tbl_insert_str = "('" + name[2:] + "')"
        else:
            tbl_insert_str = "('" + name + "')"

        query = original_query.replace("<INSERT_TABLE_NAME_HERE>", tbl_insert_str, 1)

        result = conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(query))

        # TODO: Only reading last line of the row
        value_str = ""
        for row in result:
            temp_value = row.DDL 
            value_str += temp_value

        print(value_str)

        if isView:
            # put the "V_" back into the CREATE statement
            view_name = name[2:(name.find("].[") + 3)] + "V_" + name[(name.find("].[") + 3):]
            value_str = value_str.replace(name[2:], view_name)

        return_list.append(value_str)

    return return_list
```

How can I fix this without going in and manually removing every carriage return from the source query? There are a lot of them.

Comment: Are you using some for xml to generate the query?

Comment: I am not generating any XML, nor is there any XML in the query that generates the result. The query that generates these statements is an adaptation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068143/20857342) post. The angle brackets in the question are just placeholders for the actual schema and table names.

Comment: Was just wondering if the column returned to sqlalchemy was truncated due to "for xml" mishandling. It sounds strange if sqlalchemy would go in and split some row and remove a lot of text though... So probably something more simple is going on here.

Comment: If I were to guess, I bet the default "row delimiter" character is '\r', which is what separates the lines here, and since the query is only supposed to return 1 row, it only keeps one row at a time, which is why we only see the last line. I don't know of any way to get around with behavior without changing the script.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to leave the question up because I think a general answer would be more suitable (i.e. a solution for queries that return cells with text that have carriage returns in them), but in the script that was generating this DDL, the script defines the carriage return like below:

```
DECLARE @CR NVARCHAR(max) = NCHAR(13);
```

and then uses `@CR` for carriage returns the rest of the script. So, the solution was just to use a different delimiter:

```
DECLARE @CR NVARCHAR(max) = NCHAR(32); -- space
```

Kudos to [ildanny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7924145/ildanny) and [devart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135566/devart) for the script that generates the DDL mentioned above.